# How do I set environment variables from Java?

Tags: java, environment-variables

How do I set environment variables from Java?  I see that I can do this for subprocesses using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). I have several subprocesses to start, though, so I'd rather modify the current process's environment and let the subprocesses inherit it.

There's a `System.getenv(String)` for getting a single environment variable. I can also get a `Map` of the complete set of environment variables with `System.getenv()`. But, calling `put()` on that `Map` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` -- apparently they mean for the environment to be read only. And, there's no `System.setenv()`.

So, is there any way to set environment variables in the currently running process?  If so, how?  If not, what's the rationale?  (Is it because this is Java and therefore I shouldn't be doing evil nonportable obsolete things like touching my environment?)  And if not, any good suggestions for managing the environment variable changes that I'm going to need to be feeding to several subprocesses?

Comment: System.getEnv() is intended to be universal-ish, some environments don't even have environment variables.

Comment: For anyone who needed this for a unit testing use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168884/how-to-test-code-dependent-on-environment-variables-using-junit

Comment: For Scala, use this: https://gist.github.com/vpatryshev/b1bbd15e2b759c157b58b68c58891ff4

Answer (score 110, accepted):

> (Is it because this is Java and therefore I shouldn't be doing evil nonportable obsolete things like touching my environment?)

I think you've hit the nail on the head.

A possible way to ease the burden would be to factor out a method

```
void setUpEnvironment(ProcessBuilder builder) {
    Map<String, String> env = builder.environment();
    // blah blah
}
```

and pass any `ProcessBuilder`s through it before starting them.

Also, you probably already know this, but you can start more than one process with the same `ProcessBuilder`. So if your subprocesses are the same, you don't need to do this setup over and over.

Comment: It's a shame management won't let me use a different portable language for running this set of evil, obsolete subprocesses, then. :)

Comment: @skiphoppy: no tool can set the parent's environment -- it's not a tool issue, it's an OS issue.

Comment: S.Lott, I'm not looking to set a parent's environment.  I'm looking to set my own environment.

Comment: Thanks, mmyers.  I think I'm definitely going to have to factor out such a method.  I already have a ProcessUtils class, so it's going to have to grow to manage changes to the environment.

Comment: That works great, unless it is somebody else's library (e.g. Sun's) that is launching the process.

Comment: "I think you've hit the nail on the head." Couldn't agree more, the last thing I (as a user) want is your or any program mucking with my environment variables.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy You missed the point. Nobody can play with *your environment variables* since those variables are local to a process (what you set in Windows are the default values). Each process is free to change its own variables... unless its Java.

Comment: Microsoft's .Net has a method that allows modification of the current process' environment variables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx.  In my last project, it was used to auto-configure paths to proprietary libraries.

Comment: This limitation of java is a little bit of a cop out. There is no reason for java not letting you set env vars other than "because we don't want java to do this".

Answer (score 281):

For use in scenarios where you need to set specific environment values for unit tests, you might find the following hack useful. It will change the environment variables throughout the JVM (so make sure you reset any changes after your test), but will not alter your system environment.

I found that a combination of the two dirty hacks by Edward Campbell and anonymous works best, as one does not work under linux, and the other does not work under windows 7. So to get a multiplatform evil hack I combined them:

```
protected static void setEnv(Map<String, String> newenv) throws Exception {
  try {
    Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
    Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
    theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
    env.putAll(newenv);
    Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
    theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
    Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>) theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
    cienv.putAll(newenv);
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for(Class cl : classes) {
      if("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
        Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object obj = field.get(env);
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj;
        map.clear();
        map.putAll(newenv);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This Works like a charm. Full credits to the two authors of these hacks.

Comment: Will this only change in memory, or actually change the entire environment variable in the system?

Comment: This will only change the environment variable in memory. This is good for testing, because you can set the environment variable as necessary for your test, but leave the envs in the system as they are. In fact, I would strongly discourage anyone from using this code for any other purpose than testing. This code is evil ;-)

Comment: As an FYI, the JVM creates a copy of the environment variables when it starts.  This will edit that copy, not the environment variables for the parent process that started the JVM.

Comment: I tried this on Android and it didn't seem to take.  Anyone else have any luck on Android?

Comment: Sure, `import java.lang.reflect.Field;`

Comment: @pushy Process Explorer doesn't show the newly set variable. I'm using Java 1.7.0_45 and calling setEnv() first thing in main().

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, which OS are you using? I will try to test the code with the newest java version in the coming days.

Comment: Doesn't call `setenv()`, so while this may *look* like it works, it's not actually changing environment variables at all, just changing the Java map that displays them. Look at `/proc/PID/environ` (on Linux) if you don't believe me.

Comment: I believe you just fine. Also, this is exactly what most people need. This is a very dirty hack to change environment variables during unit testing. The changes will not be (and should not be) seen outside of the JVM. Also, this issue was already discussed in comments #3 and #4. It may be worthwhile to state that fact in the answer text though.

Comment: @pushy the code segment `cl.getDeclaredField("m");` also throws `NoSuchFieldException` so we may need to throw it in method declaration or else we need to have another `try catch` in initial `catch (NoSuchFieldException e) `

Comment: If you want to avoid hardcoding the class string and doing that loop to find the correct class, I found this approach worked: `var unmodifiablemapClass = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>()).getClass()`

(code untested as I actually wrote it in Kotlin, but you get the idea)

Comment: I also needed to add a cienv.clear(); and env.clear(); as my unit test required verifying that if the env was not set a correct error would be shown. This is a great set of code for solving the problem though!

Comment: prepend `newenv.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull)` to avoid potential bugs

Comment: I was trying to use this on a gradle project of mine, since I was aiming to automatically find and set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable if it wasn't already defined. But it looks like this code could be cleaning the other environment variables (in the catch we have this), one other thing is that we are letting our fields accessible, which could not be a good thing, and I don't know why but this was causing another problem too. So, for now, I'm not using it, but it could be nice to find improvements for it.

Comment: What would be the solution for production then?

Comment: Works great @pushy! @Arttu the best considerable solution for production would  be to have these environment variables defined in the server.

Comment: the method not working,ProcessEnvironment has no theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment field in jdk8!

Comment: Doesn't work in OpenJDK 17. And the corresponding implementation differs from Linux to Windows.

Comment: Hi @EdGomoliako Do you mind trying out my solution which uses `Unsafe`? I'm not sure if you resolved your issue yet.

Answer (score 92):

```
public static void set(Map<String, String> newenv) throws Exception {
    Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for(Class cl : classes) {
        if("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
            Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object obj = field.get(env);
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) obj;
            map.clear();
            map.putAll(newenv);
        }
    }
}
```

Or to add/update a single var and removing the loop as per thejoshwolfe's suggestion.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
  public static void updateEnv(String name, String val) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    Field field = env.getClass().getDeclaredField("m");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    ((Map<String, String>) field.get(env)).put(name, val);
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like that would modify the map in memory, but would it save the value to the system?

Comment: well it does change the memory map of environment variables. i guess that suffices in a whole lot of use-cases.  
@Edward - gosh, it's hard to imagine how this solution was figured out in the first place!

Comment: This won't change the environment variables on the system, but will change them in the current invocation of Java. This is very useful for unit testing.

Comment: This one doesn't work on Windows 7 x64; one with theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment does.

Comment: why not use `Class<?> cl = env.getClass();` instead of that for loop?

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! I've been writing integration tests for some code that uses a third party tool that, for some reason, only lets you modify its absurdly short default timeout length with an environmental variable.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in my integration test, anonymous answer does though.

Comment: it stopped working on java17

Answer (score 39):

Setting single environment variables (based on answer by Edward Campbell):

```
public static void setEnv(String key, String value) {
    try {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        Class<?> cl = env.getClass();
        Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, String> writableEnv = (Map<String, String>) field.get(env);
        writableEnv.put(key, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to set environment variable", e);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

First, put the method in any class you want, e.g. SystemUtil. Then call it statically:

```
SystemUtil.setEnv("SHELL", "/bin/bash");
```

If you call `System.getenv("SHELL")` after this, you'll get `"/bin/bash"` back.

Comment: The above does not work in windows 10, but _will_ work in linux.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't try it myself on Windows. Do you get an error, @mengchengfeng?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak We didn't see any error messages, it just didn't work...

Comment: it works on windows 10 and linux for me. Congratulations !

Comment: Why would this be Linux/Mac only?  Obviously Bash may not be present by default, but the Java code here is not platform-dependent.

Comment: @MatthewRead I didn't test on Windows, but one of the commenters reported it not working. If you can confirm it works on Windows, feel free to change the answer (or let me know and I'll happily edit)

Comment: That works Red Hat linux 8.5 using OpenJDK 11.0.11 but I get ugly warnings:

    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: and it stopped working on java17

Comment: Among all wired & complicated answers I came about, this one is the simplest. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Do variables set this way get inherited by subprocesses, as specified in the original question? I would be amazed if they do, since this looks like it is not modifying the process's native environment, just Java's parsed copy of it.

Answer (score 24):

```
// this is a dirty hack - but should be ok for a unittest.
private void setNewEnvironmentHack(Map<String, String> newenv) throws Exception
{
  Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
  Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
  theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
  Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);
  env.clear();
  env.putAll(newenv);
  Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
  theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
  Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>) theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
  cienv.clear();
  cienv.putAll(newenv);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

on Android the interface is exposed via Libcore.os as a kind of hidden API.

```
Libcore.os.setenv("VAR", "value", bOverwrite);
Libcore.os.getenv("VAR"));
```

The Libcore class as well as the interface OS is public. Just the class declaration is missing and need to be shown to the linker. No need to add the classes to the application, but it also does not hurt if it is included.

```
package libcore.io;

public final class Libcore {
    private Libcore() { }

    public static Os os;
}

package libcore.io;

public interface Os {
    public String getenv(String name);
    public void setenv(String name, String value, boolean overwrite) throws ErrnoException;
}
```

Comment: Tested and working on Android 4.4.4 (CM11). P.S. The only adjustment I made was replacing `throws ErrnoException` with `throws Exception`.

Comment: API 21, has `Os.setEnv` now. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#setenv(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)

Comment: Potentially defunct now with Pie's new restrictions:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Answer (score 12):

This is a combination of @paul-blair 's answer converted to Java which includes some cleanups pointed out by paul blair and some mistakes that seem to have been inside @pushy 's code which is made up of @Edward Campbell and anonymous.

I cannot emphasize how much this code should ONLY be used in testing and is extremely hacky. But for cases where you need the environment setup in tests it is exactly what I needed.

This also includes some minor touches of mine that allow the code to work on both Windows running on

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

as well as Centos running on

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

The implementation:

```
/**
 * Sets an environment variable FOR THE CURRENT RUN OF THE JVM
 * Does not actually modify the system's environment variables,
 *  but rather only the copy of the variables that java has taken,
 *  and hence should only be used for testing purposes!
 * @param key The Name of the variable to set
 * @param value The value of the variable to set
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K,V> void setenv(final String key, final String value) {
    try {
        /// we obtain the actual environment
        final Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
        final Field theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
        final boolean environmentAccessibility = theEnvironmentField.isAccessible();
        theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);

        final Map<K,V> env = (Map<K, V>) theEnvironmentField.get(null);

        if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
            // This is all that is needed on windows running java jdk 1.8.0_92
            if (value == null) {
                env.remove(key);
            } else {
                env.put((K) key, (V) value);
            }
        } else {
            // This is triggered to work on openjdk 1.8.0_91
            // The ProcessEnvironment$Variable is the key of the map
            final Class<K> variableClass = (Class<K>) Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Variable");
            final Method convertToVariable = variableClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
            final boolean conversionVariableAccessibility = convertToVariable.isAccessible();
            convertToVariable.setAccessible(true);

            // The ProcessEnvironment$Value is the value fo the map
            final Class<V> valueClass = (Class<V>) Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Value");
            final Method convertToValue = valueClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
            final boolean conversionValueAccessibility = convertToValue.isAccessible();
            convertToValue.setAccessible(true);

            if (value == null) {
                env.remove(convertToVariable.invoke(null, key));
            } else {
                // we place the new value inside the map after conversion so as to
                // avoid class cast exceptions when rerunning this code
                env.put((K) convertToVariable.invoke(null, key), (V) convertToValue.invoke(null, value));

                // reset accessibility to what they were
                convertToValue.setAccessible(conversionValueAccessibility);
                convertToVariable.setAccessible(conversionVariableAccessibility);
            }
        }
        // reset environment accessibility
        theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(environmentAccessibility);

        // we apply the same to the case insensitive environment
        final Field theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
        final boolean insensitiveAccessibility = theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.isAccessible();
        theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
        // Not entirely sure if this needs to be casted to ProcessEnvironment$Variable and $Value as well
        final Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>) theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null);
        if (value == null) {
            // remove if null
            cienv.remove(key);
        } else {
            cienv.put(key, value);
        }
        theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(insensitiveAccessibility);
    } catch (final ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed setting environment variable <"+key+"> to <"+value+">", e);
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // we could not find theEnvironment
        final Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        Stream.of(Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses())
                // obtain the declared classes of type $UnmodifiableMap
                .filter(c1 -> "java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(c1.getName()))
                .map(c1 -> {
                    try {
                        return c1.getDeclaredField("m");
                    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException e1) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed setting environment variable <"+key+"> to <"+value+"> when locating in-class memory map of environment", e1);
                    }
                })
                .forEach(field -> {
                    try {
                        final boolean fieldAccessibility = field.isAccessible();
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        // we obtain the environment
                        final Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) field.get(env);
                        if (value == null) {
                            // remove if null
                            map.remove(key);
                        } else {
                            map.put(key, value);
                        }
                        // reset accessibility
                        field.setAccessible(fieldAccessibility);
                    } catch (final ConcurrentModificationException e1) {
                        // This may happen if we keep backups of the environment before calling this method
                        // as the map that we kept as a backup may be picked up inside this block.
                        // So we simply skip this attempt and continue adjusting the other maps
                        // To avoid this one should always keep individual keys/value backups not the entire map
                        LOGGER.info("Attempted to modify source map: "+field.getDeclaringClass()+"#"+field.getName(), e1);
                    } catch (final IllegalAccessException e1) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed setting environment variable <"+key+"> to <"+value+">. Unable to access field!", e1);
                    }
                });
    }
    LOGGER.info("Set environment variable <"+key+"> to <"+value+">. Sanity Check: "+System.getenv(key));
}
```

Comment: it works, use like this:
    `setenv("coba","coba value");`
    `System.out.println(System.getenv("coba"));`

  result:
`Set environment variable <coba> to <coba value>. Sanity Check: coba`
`value coba value`

Answer (score 10):

It turns out that the solution from @pushy/@anonymous/@Edward Campbell does not work on Android because Android is not really Java.  Specifically, Android does not have `java.lang.ProcessEnvironment` at all.  But it turns out to be easier in Android, you just need to do a JNI call to POSIX `setenv()`:

In C/JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_posixtest_Posix_setenv
  (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jstring key, jstring value, jboolean overwrite)
{
    char* k = (char *) (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, key, NULL);
    char* v = (char *) (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, value, NULL);
    int err = setenv(k, v, overwrite);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, key, k);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, value, v);
    return err;
}
```

And in Java:

```java
public class Posix {

    public static native int setenv(String key, String value, boolean overwrite);

    private void runTest() {
        Posix.setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "foo", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Like most people who have found this thread, I was writing some unit tests and needed to modify the environment variables to set the correct conditions for the test to run.  However, I found the most upvoted answers had some issues and/or were very cryptic or overly complicated.  Hopefully this will help others to sort out the solution more quickly.

First off, I finally found @Hubert Grzeskowiak's solution to be the simplest and it worked for me.  I wish I would have come to that one first.  It's based on @Edward Campbell's answer, but without the complicating for loop search.

However, I started with @pushy's solution, which got the most upvotes. It is a combo of @anonymous and @Edward Campbell's.  @pushy claims both approaches are needed to cover both Linux and Windows environments.  I'm running under OS X and find that both work (once an issue with @anonymous approach is fixed).  As others have noted, this solution works most of the time, but not all.

I think the source of most of the confusion comes from @anonymous's solution operating on the 'theEnvironment' field.  Looking at the definition of the [ProcessEnvironment](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ProcessEnvironment.java) structure, 'theEnvironment' is not a Map< String, String > but rather it is a Map< Variable, Value >.  Clearing the map works fine, but the putAll operation rebuilds the map a Map< String, String >, which potentially causes problems when subsequent operations operate on the data structure using the normal API that expects Map< Variable, Value >.  Also, accessing/removing individual elements is a problem.  The solution is to access 'theEnvironment' indirectly through 'theUnmodifiableEnvironment'.  But since this is a type [UnmodifiableMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java?av=f#1439) the access must be done through the private variable 'm' of the UnmodifiableMap type.  See getModifiableEnvironmentMap2 in code below.

In my case I needed to remove some of the environment variables for my test (the others should be unchanged).  Then I wanted to restore the environment variables to their prior state after the test.  The routines below make that straight forward to do.  I tested both versions of getModifiableEnvironmentMap on OS X, and both work equivalently.  Though based on comments in this thread, one may be a better choice than the other depending on the environment.

Note: I did not include access to the 'theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField' since that seems to be Windows specific and I had no way to test it, but adding it should be straight forward.

```
private Map<String, String> getModifiableEnvironmentMap() {
    try {
        Map<String,String> unmodifiableEnv = System.getenv();
        Class<?> cl = unmodifiableEnv.getClass();
        Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String,String> modifiableEnv = (Map<String,String>) field.get(unmodifiableEnv);
        return modifiableEnv;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to access writable environment variable map.");
    }
}

private Map<String, String> getModifiableEnvironmentMap2() {
    try {
        Class<?> processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
        Field theUnmodifiableEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theUnmodifiableEnvironment");
        theUnmodifiableEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String,String> theUnmodifiableEnvironment = (Map<String,String>)theUnmodifiableEnvironmentField.get(null);

        Class<?> theUnmodifiableEnvironmentClass = theUnmodifiableEnvironment.getClass();
        Field theModifiableEnvField = theUnmodifiableEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("m");
        theModifiableEnvField.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String,String> modifiableEnv = (Map<String,String>) theModifiableEnvField.get(theUnmodifiableEnvironment);
        return modifiableEnv;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to access writable environment variable map.");
    }
}

private Map<String, String> clearEnvironmentVars(String[] keys) {

    Map<String,String> modifiableEnv = getModifiableEnvironmentMap();

    HashMap<String, String> savedVals = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(String k : keys) {
        String val = modifiableEnv.remove(k);
        if (val != null) { savedVals.put(k, val); }
    }
    return savedVals;
}

private void setEnvironmentVars(Map<String, String> varMap) {
    getModifiableEnvironmentMap().putAll(varMap);   
}

@Test
public void myTest() {
    String[] keys = { "key1", "key2", "key3" };
    Map<String, String> savedVars = clearEnvironmentVars(keys);

    // do test

    setEnvironmentVars(savedVars);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly my use case and under mac os x too.

Comment: Liked this so much I rustled up a slightly simpler version for Groovy, see below.

Comment: For unit tests, I'd really recommend using one of the test libraries that does this for you. There's JUnit Pioneer, System Stubs, System Rules and System Lambda.

Answer (score 9):

There are a three libraries out there that can do this during unit tests.

There's Stefan Birkner's System Rules and System Lambda - https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-rules-junit which allow you to do something like:

```java
public class JUnitTest {

    @Rule
    public EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables();

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        environmentVariables.set("SOME_VARIABLE", "myValue");
        
        // now System.getenv does what you want
    }
}
```

or for System-Lambda:

```java
@Test
void execute_code_with_environment_variables(
) throws Exception {
  List<String> values = withEnvironmentVariable("first", "first value")
    .and("second", "second value")
    .execute(() -> asList(
      System.getenv("first"),
      System.getenv("second")
    ));
  assertEquals(
    asList("first value", "second value"),
    values
  );
}
```

The above features are also available as JUnit 5 extension via System Stubs:

```java
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)
class SomeTest {

    @SystemStub
    private EnvironmentVariables;

    @Test
    void theTest() {
        environmentVariables.set("SOME_VARIABLE", "myValue");
        
        // now System.getenv does what you want

    }

}
```

System Stubs is backwards compatible with System Lambda and System Rules, but supports JUnit 5.

Alternatively, there's also JUnit Pioneer - https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer, which allows for environment variables to be set at test time via annotations.

Comment: JUnit Pioneer is excellent.  A simple `@SetEnvironmentVariable(key = "SOME_VARIABLE", value = "myValue")` on the test method and you're good to go.

Comment: It is, but the environment variable value has to be known at coding time, which doesn't work for setting things like dynamic ports etc.

Answer (score 8):

Tried pushy's answer above and it worked for the most part. However, in certain circumstances, I would see this exception:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Variable
```

This turns out to happen when the method was called more than once, owing to the implementation of certain inner classes of `ProcessEnvironment.` If the `setEnv(..)` method is called more than once, when the keys are retrieved from the `theEnvironment` map, they are now strings (having been put in as strings by the first invocation of `setEnv(...)` ) and cannot be cast to the map's generic type, `Variable,` which is a private inner class of `ProcessEnvironment.`

A fixed version (in Scala), is below. Hopefully it isn't too difficult to carry over into Java.

```
def setEnv(newenv: java.util.Map[String, String]): Unit = {
  try {
    val processEnvironmentClass = JavaClass.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment")
    val theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment")
    theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true)

    val variableClass = JavaClass.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Variable")
    val convertToVariable = variableClass.getMethod("valueOf", classOf[java.lang.String])
    convertToVariable.setAccessible(true)

    val valueClass = JavaClass.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Value")
    val convertToValue = valueClass.getMethod("valueOf", classOf[java.lang.String])
    convertToValue.setAccessible(true)

    val sampleVariable = convertToVariable.invoke(null, "")
    val sampleValue = convertToValue.invoke(null, "")
    val env = theEnvironmentField.get(null).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[sampleVariable.type, sampleValue.type]]
    newenv.foreach { case (k, v) => {
        val variable = convertToVariable.invoke(null, k).asInstanceOf[sampleVariable.type]
        val value = convertToValue.invoke(null, v).asInstanceOf[sampleValue.type]
        env.put(variable, value)
      }
    }

    val theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment")
    theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true)
    val cienv = theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]
    cienv.putAll(newenv);
  }
  catch {
    case e : NoSuchFieldException => {
      try {
        val classes = classOf[java.util.Collections].getDeclaredClasses
        val env = System.getenv()
        classes foreach (cl => {
          if("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap" == cl.getName) {
            val field = cl.getDeclaredField("m")
            field.setAccessible(true)
            val map = field.get(env).asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, String]]
            // map.clear() // Not sure why this was in the code. It means we need to set all required environment variables.
            map.putAll(newenv)
          }
        })
      } catch {
        case e2: Exception => e2.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
    case e1: Exception => e1.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is JavaClass defined?

Comment: Presumably `import java.lang.{Class => JavaClass}`.

Comment: Implementation of java.lang.ProcessEnvironment is different on different platforms even for the same build. For example, there is no class java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$Variable in the implementation of Windows but this class exists in one for Linux. You can easily check it. Just download tar.gz JDK distribution for Linux and extract the source from src.zip then compare it with the same file from the distribution for Windows. They are totally different in JDK 1.8.0_181. I have not checked them in Java 10 but I will not be surprised if there is the same picture.

Answer (score 8):

If you are facing this problem with testing like me, and you are using Junit5, [Junit-pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org/) comes with very helpful annotations. [maven release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer)

example:

```
@Test
@SetEnvironmentVariable(key = "some variable",value = "new value")
void test() {
    assertThat(System.getenv("some variable")).
        isEqualTo("new value");
}
```

can not recommend it enough.

Answer (score 5):

Poking around online, it looks like it might be possible to do this with JNI.  You'd then have to make a call to putenv() from C, and you'd (presumably) have to do it in a way that worked on both Windows and UNIX.

If all that can be done, it surely wouldn't be too hard for Java itself to support this instead of putting me in a straight jacket.

A Perl-speaking friend elsewhere suggests that this is because environment variables are process global and Java is striving for good isolation for good design.

Comment: Yes, you can set the processes environment from C code.  But I wouldn't count on that working in Java.  There is a good chance that the JVM copies the environment into Java String objects during startup, so your changes would not be used for future JVM operations.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, Darron.  There's probably a good chance you're right.

Comment: @Darron many of the reasons one would want to do this have nothing at all to do with what the JVM thinks the environment is. (Think of setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before calling `Runtime.loadLibrary()`; the `dlopen()` call it invokes looks at the _real_ environment, not at Java's idea of same).

Comment: This works for subprocesses started by a native library (which in my case is most of them), but unfortunately does not work for subprocesses started by Java's Process or ProcessBuilder classes.

Comment: This won't modify the environment variables in the running JVM. They're loaded when the process starts and they're immutable, unless you deliberately find a way to hack them.

For launching a new process, you get to specify its environment variables. That's easily done, whether it's before your JVM process starts, or a child process spawned by your JVM

Answer (score 5):

Setting the environment variables in the current Java process which uses native code (a dll) which relies on the environment variable in question, only works when you set this environment variable natively.

Most of the examples here you are changing the maps in the JVM, but will not work native.

One way I saw is through JNI, which probably works as well.
Another way is using **JNA Platform** by using the **Kernel32** interface (windows only) For example:

```
private static void setEnv(String key, String value) {
    if(isWindows()) {
        if (!Kernel32.INSTANCE.SetEnvironmentVariable(key, value)) {
            System.err.println("Unable to set the environemnt variable: " + key);
        }
    }
}
```

For a unix like OS, the **LibCAPI** interface can be used, but have not tried that one.

Comment: `if( isMac() || isLinux() ) { if( LibC.INSTANCE.setenv( key, value, 1 ) != 0 ) { System.err.println( "Unable to set the environemnt variable: " + key ); } }` does the trick on linux and macos.

Answer (score 3):

just use reflect, like `setEnv("k1","v1")`

```java
    private void setEnv(String key, String val) throws Exception {
        getModifiableEnv().put(key, val);
    }
    
    private Map<String, String> getModifiableEnv() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> unmodifiableEnv = System.getenv();
        Field field = unmodifiableEnv.getClass().getDeclaredField("m");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (Map<String, String>) field.get(unmodifiableEnv);
    }
```

need

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Map;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tim Ryan's answer worked for me... but I wanted it for Groovy (Spock context for example), and simplissimo:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field

def getModifiableEnvironmentMap() {
    def unmodifiableEnv = System.getenv()
    Class cl = unmodifiableEnv.getClass()
    Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m")
    field.accessible = true
    field.get(unmodifiableEnv)
}

def clearEnvironmentVars( def keys ) {
    def savedVals = [:]
    keys.each{ key ->
        String val = modifiableEnvironmentMap.remove(key)
        // thinking about it, I'm not sure why we need this test for null
        // but haven't yet done any experiments
        if( val != null ) {
            savedVals.put( key, val )
        }
    }
    savedVals
}

def setEnvironmentVars(Map varMap) {
    modifiableEnvironmentMap.putAll(varMap)
}

// pretend existing Env Var doesn't exist
def PATHVal1 = System.env.PATH
println "PATH val1 |$PATHVal1|"
String[] keys = ["PATH", "key2", "key3"]
def savedVars = clearEnvironmentVars(keys)
def PATHVal2 = System.env.PATH
println "PATH val2 |$PATHVal2|"

// return to reality
setEnvironmentVars(savedVars)
def PATHVal3 = System.env.PATH
println "PATH val3 |$PATHVal3|"
println "System.env |$System.env|"

// pretend a non-existent Env Var exists
setEnvironmentVars( [ 'key4' : 'key4Val' ])
println "key4 val |$System.env.key4|"
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this thread as I had a similar requirement where I needed to set (or update) an Environment Variable (permanently).

So I looked in to - How to set an environment variable permanently from Command Prompt and it was very simple!

```
setx JAVA_LOC C:/Java/JDK
```

Then I just implemented the same in my code
Here's what I used (suppose - JAVA_LOC is the env. variable name)

```
        String cmdCommand = "setx JAVA_LOC " + "C:/Java/JDK";
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
            processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", cmdCommand);
            processBuilder.start();
```

ProcessBuilder fires-up a cmd.exe and passes the command that you want.
The environment variable is retained even if you kill JVM/reboot the system as it has no relation with the JVM/Program's lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Kotlin evil version of the @pushy's evil [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201825/727184) =)

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun setEnv(newenv: Map<String, String>) {
    try {
        val processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment")
        val theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment")
        theEnvironmentField.isAccessible = true
        val env = theEnvironmentField.get(null) as MutableMap<String, String>
        env.putAll(newenv)
        val theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment")
        theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.isAccessible = true
        val cienv = theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null) as MutableMap<String, String>
        cienv.putAll(newenv)
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        val classes = Collections::class.java.getDeclaredClasses()
        val env = System.getenv()
        for (cl in classes) {
            if ("java.util.Collections\$UnmodifiableMap" == cl.getName()) {
                val field = cl.getDeclaredField("m")
                field.setAccessible(true)
                val obj = field.get(env)
                val map = obj as MutableMap<String, String>
                map.clear()
                map.putAll(newenv)
            }
        }
    }
```

It is working in macOS Mojave at least.

Answer (score 0):

A version in Kotlin, in this algorithm I created a decorator that allows you to set and get variables from the environment.

```
import java.util.Collections
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty
​
class EnvironmentDelegate {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return System.getenv(property.name) ?: "-"
    }
​
    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        val key = property.name
​
        val classes: Array<Class<*>> = Collections::class.java.declaredClasses
        val env = System.getenv()
​
        val cl = classes.first { "java.util.Collections\$UnmodifiableMap" == it.name }
​
        val field = cl.getDeclaredField("m")
        field.isAccessible = true
        val obj = field[env]
        val map = obj as MutableMap<String, String>
        map.putAll(mapOf(key to value))
    }
}
​
class KnownProperties {
    var JAVA_HOME: String by EnvironmentDelegate()
    var sample: String by EnvironmentDelegate()
}
​
fun main() {
    val knowProps = KnownProperties()
    knowProps.sample = "2"
​
    println("Java Home: ${knowProps.JAVA_HOME}")
    println("Sample: ${knowProps.sample}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As many of you know, Java 17 removed a lot of Reflection capabilities for the internal modules. This solution uses `Unsafe` to bypass that but I strongly recommend against doing so unless you really have to do this.

```java
  public static void setEnvironmentalVariable(@NotNull final String key, @NotNull final String value) {
    try {
      final Map<String, String> unwritable = System.getenv();
      final Map<String, String> writable =
              (Map<String, String>) getField(unwritable, "m");
      writable.put(key, value);
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  public static @NotNull Object getField(@NotNull final Object object, @NotNull final String name)
      throws NoSuchFieldException {
    return getField(object.getClass(), object, name);
  }

  public static @NotNull Object getField(
      @NotNull final Class<?> clazz, @NotNull final Object object, @NotNull final String name)
      throws NoSuchFieldException {
    return UNSAFE.getObject(object, UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset(clazz.getDeclaredField(name)));
  }
```

(Assume the UNSAFE constant is the `Unsafe` singleton)

Answer (score -1):

[jython](/questions/tagged/jython) variant based on [@pushy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201825/2249575) answer, works on windows.

```
def set_env(newenv):
    from java.lang import Class
    process_environment = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment")
    environment_field =  process_environment.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment")
    environment_field.setAccessible(True)
    env = environment_field.get(None)
    env.putAll(newenv)
    invariant_environment_field = process_environment.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
    invariant_environment_field.setAccessible(True)
    invevn = invariant_environment_field.get(None)
    invevn.putAll(newenv)
```

Usage:

```
old_environ = dict(os.environ)
old_environ['EPM_ORACLE_HOME'] = r"E:\Oracle\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1"
set_env(old_environ)
```

Answer (score -2):

Kotlin implementation I recently made based on Edward's answer:

```
fun setEnv(newEnv: Map<String, String>) {
    val unmodifiableMapClass = Collections.unmodifiableMap<Any, Any>(mapOf()).javaClass
    with(unmodifiableMapClass.getDeclaredField("m")) {
        isAccessible = true
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        get(System.getenv()) as MutableMap<String, String>
    }.apply {
        clear()
        putAll(newEnv)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you work with SpringBoot you can add specifying the environmental variable in the following property:

```
was.app.config.properties.toSystemProperties
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit?

Comment: System properties are not the same as environmental variables.

Answer (score -18):

You can pass parameters into your initial java process with -D:

```
java -cp <classpath> -Dkey1=value -Dkey2=value ...
```

Comment: The values are not known at execution time; they become known during the program's execution when the user provides/selects them.  And that sets only system properties, not environment variables.

Comment: Then in that case you probably want to find a regular way (via the args[] parameter to the main method) to invoke your subprocesses.

Comment: matt b, the regular way is via ProcessBuilder, as mentioned in my original question. :)

Comment: -D parameters are available through `System.getProperty` and are not the same as `System.getenv`.

Besides, the `System` class also allows to set these properties statically using `setProperty`