# Setting environment variable with maven 2.x

Tags: linux, maven-2, variables, environment, setting

Is it possible to set environment variable with maven (OS: Linux)?

I already have user-defined properties (in the pom and in profiles.xml)....my problem is, how to execute following from Maven

```
export GGA_FRE=/path
```

So will be possible, that every developer can set his own path for the `GGA_FRE`.

Comment: Maven has some env and java variables built-in. Which one (as an example) do you want to set ?

Comment: i want to set my own environment var....for exmple the GGA_FRE.

Comment: Why do you need to set them? Use them from outside Maven?

Comment: Yes....and i want, that every developer can set different path for the GGA_FRE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer is not correct, at least not completely (see comments).**
 Unfortunately I can't delete it as it has been accepted. Your milage may vary.

---

Use the [exec:exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) mojo.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>exportVar</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>export</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>GGA_FRE=${my.path}</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

now call it like this `mvn install -Dmy.path=/var/users/groucho`

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this works? I've tried it and it doesn't work for me. I think that exec:exec would execute the command in a spawned shell, which would take the changed environment down with it when it exits immediately afterwards.

Comment: @Anonymoose that might be right, probably you should ask a follow-up question at http://superuser.com to determine the exact command necessary (if there is one). I'm not a shell guru.

Comment: I don't understand why answers that are incorrect are a) voted up and b) accepted.

Comment: I said above that the mechanism is as close as you'll get from inside Maven. Figure out the correct shell command and it will work. This is a maven question, not a shell question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Java way to set environment variable the way export command does (so that it is avaliable outside of Java). (see for example this question: [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java))

However, you might hack you way around: for example use maven-exec plugin to run a shell script and then set the variable in the script. You might pass a parameter to your script to specify the variable value.
(note that I have not tested this)