# batch file execution in c#

Tags: c#, file, batch-file

I am running a Java batch file from C#. If I run it by double clicking it executes successfully, but if I run it from C# code it gives exception in thread

> "exception in "main" thread
>   java.lang.noclassdeffoundError"..

what can be the reason and how can it be solved? I am using the code:

```
var si = new ProcessStartInfo();

si.CreateNoWindow = true;
si.FileName = "batch-file path";
si.UseShellExecute = true;

Process.Start(si);
```

Comment: I guess the working directory could be relevant for the Java application.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing some of the parameters that would be included in your systems environment variables.

Comment: I really can't because I don't know anything about the Java program you are trying to run.  But this other OS article might help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Answer (score 0):

Try setting working directory like this

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\";
```

Also, try few other options as mentioned here,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/20992653-dabf-4b31-85f7-e7bfbfb4557c

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code as the first line to your batch file.

```
@cd /d %~dp0
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use batch_process_path + "\" + instead use Path.Combine() to make sure the path is correctly fitted with slashes.

Also [read this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5b13859e-545f-4bd6-b759-348187753c4e) "When UseShellExecute is true, the WorkingDirectory property specifies the location of the executable"

So set it to false.