# Batch file execution in c#

Tags: c#, file, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [batch file execution in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978737/batch-file-execution-in-c)

I am using c# to run Java batch file..
But the problem is, that it's not taking the path
I am using in the code as:

```
 var si = new ProcessStartInfo();
            si.CreateNoWindow = true;
            si.WorkingDirectory = batch_process_path;
            si.FileName = batch_process_path + "\\" +  "run.bat";
            si.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process.Start(si.FileName);
```

According to my logic the process should start from the `si.working` directory. But it is starting from "C:". But if I give the static path it will execute successfully..
I can't understand what the problem is.
Please help me out.

Comment: You should edit your existing question with the new information instead of creating a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `batch_process_path + "\\" +` instead use `Path.Combine()` to make sure the path is correctly fitted with slashes.

Also [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) "When UseShellExecute is true, the WorkingDirectory property specifies the location of the executable"

So set it to false.