# Setting of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH within a Java application

Tags: java, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

How can I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH from within a Java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is an *environment* varable, not a system properety. As tehre is no System.setEnv method I doubt you can do what you seek for. Read here: [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)