# Passing custom environment variables to maven cargo

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, maven-cargo

I'm looking for a way to pass environment variables into a cargo container.  Something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo>
  <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <environmentVariables>
      <myCustomVariable>value</myCustomVariable>
      ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, The cargo only allow to pass the system properties as mentioning at [Passing system properties](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Passing+system+properties) and [Maven Tips](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Tips) as the following example: -

```
<container>
  [...]
  <systemProperties>
    <myproperty>myvalue</myproperty>
  </systemProperties>
</container>
```

The workaround may be link that system properties to the environment variable as the following example:-

```
<container>
  [...]
  <systemProperties>
    <myproperty>${env.MY_ENV_VAR}</myproperty>
  </systemProperties>
</container>
```

Normally we are only able to set the environment variable by using the OS way. Anyhow there also is a workaround for setting it by using Java as mentioning at [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java).

I always use this tip for setting up the environment variables during unit testing by putting them to the JUnit test suit with `@BeforeClass` and set them to be empty String with `@AfterClass`.

Please note that the formal Java Tutorial also mentions about [Environment Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) and [Passing Environment Variables to New Processes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

I hope this may help.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work with glassfish 4. I always get the property as null. To retrieve the property in java code I use: System.getenv("myproperty"). I also tried System.getProperty("myproperty") but that didn't work either.