# Run command in linux terminal using java program?

Tags: java, linux

I want to run `unset DISPLAY` as a command in the linux terminal, using a Java program.

I tried using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("unset DISPLAY");`, but it doesn't work.

What could I do here?

Comment: hmm.. writing programs using the language you know best ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run it using bash executable like this:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c \"unset DISPLAY\"");
```

Comment: similarly for a windows env it would be cmd instead of /bin/bash -c

Comment: But still it should be noted that a simple `unset DISPLAY` will not effect anything after the bash (or cmd or ...) process exits, see Chris's answer.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: Indeed, any changes in env variables will only be see by sub shell (child shell) that gets created.

Answer (score 6):

This won't work, and here's why. Environment variables are inherited from the parent process. A child can't control a parent's environment. Here's what's happening in your setup:

```
 bash   ->   java   ->   unset
   |           |           |
 parent      child     grand-child
   |           |           |
unaffected unaffected   affected
```

So in actuality your command IS working, however it's not having the effect you want it to. Sadly java won't be able to change the parent's environment.

Your java program *can* modify environment variables of its own, and any children spawned by java will inherit those variables. So you could potentially have java launch a bash shell for you, and then use that bash shell interactively, but that seems like a lot of overhead.

See this post for how to set java's environment variables:
[How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

If you're willing to sidestep the whole java problem, what most people do in this situation is source a special file. For example, create a file called "no-x.sh" that looks like this:

```
# Unset the display variable
unset DISPLAY
```

And then from your current (interactive) shell, source the file like this:

```
$> source no-x.sh
```

and now your main bash shell has had its environment changed. Note that this is a HACK (or for all of you bash zealots out there -- a feature) and you should never expect to duplicate this functionality with anything else (like java).