# Using export in Java

Tags: java, export

I am using java to call another program which relies on an exported environment variable to function:

```
SOME_VARIABLE=/home/..
export SOME_VARIABLE
```

How can I use java to set this variable, so that I can use this program on more than just one machine? Essentially I want to be able to emulate the above commands via java.

Comment: You may also want to check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Comment: How are you calling the other program and is that Java or something else?

Answer (score 7):

You can set environment variables when using `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` or `java.lang.Processbuilder` to call the other program.

With Processbuilder, you can do:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("your command");
processBuilder.environment().put("SOME_VARIABLE", "/home/..");
processBuilder.start();
```

With Runtime, it's:

```
Map<String, String> environment = new HashMap<String, String>(System.getenv());
environment.put("SOME_VARIABLE", "/home/..");
String[] envp = new String[environment.size()];
int count = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : environment.entrySet()) {
    envp[count++] = entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue();
}

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command", envp);
```

Comment: Nice work, especially treating the environment has a hashmap, rather than blindly adding variables to the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [`System#setProperty(String property, String value)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), though I'm not sure if this will change anything outside of the current JVM, which means this environment variable will only be available to processes that the current JVM starts.