# Is possible to run export command from java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [run shell command from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460297/run-shell-command-from-java)

I want to export some variable so I have this command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("export a=b");
```

what is wrong with this command because this throw exeption:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: You can use ProcessBuilder. See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish.  You can run a shell command by invoking `bash` in a `ProcessBuilder`, but the effect of the `export` will extend only to that invocation.  You cannot modify the parent shell's environment from within a Java program.

Comment: @JimGarrison's comment should be the accepted solution.  It depends on what the user is aiming to accomplish.  I found this answer very useful which contains an example similar to @Manish's link, but with examples for both `ProcessBuilder` as well as `Runtime.exec()` http://stackoverflow.com/a/7370477/3196753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

export is a shell command, not a program.The best way to do this would be to encapsulate all of the shell logic into a single shell script and then execute "/bin/sh /path/to/file.sh"

Comment: If the `export` only needs to occur for the lifespan of the spawned process, @JimGarrison's comment above is more comprehensive.