# Intellij Terminal behaving differently than Ubuntu Terminal for pulseaudio/pacmd/pactrl commands

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, terminal, pulseaudio

I'm trying to run some pulseaudio operations with `ProcessBuilder` in Java, e.g. `pacmd list-source-outputs` on Ubuntu 18.04. When I run the code directly from Intellij it says `No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.`
However, if I go to build/classes/java/main and execute `java MyMainClass` it works as expected.

I assume that it has something to with how the Intellij terminal is integrated. It doesn't seem to behave the same as the OS terminal (see image). Does anyone have more insights about the Intellij Terminal?

```
Process p = null;
try {
    p = new ProcessBuilder("pacmd", "list-source-outputs").start();

    printStream(p.getInputStream());
    printStream(p.getErrorStream());

    p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: Both terminals]

Edit: My Terminal settings:

[image: Intellij Terminal settings]

[image: Linux Terminal]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same shell in Intellij? This might be helpful to you https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html

Comment: you can edit the shell from terminal in the settings. Open settings and write terminal. There you see the current shell.

Comment: I added the settings pictures. Are there more options to see whether it is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with pulseaudio. What worked for me was to call

```
export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH=/run/user/1000/pulse
```

before running any pulseaudio/pacmd/pacntl command. The export command [doesn't seem to work from runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758267/is-possible-to-run-export-command-from-java). However, you can create a shell file and then execute your commands:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH=/run/user/1000/pulse
pacmd list-source-outputs
```

In Java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh test.sh");
```

**Easier handling for dynamic calling:**

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH=/run/user/1000/pulse
$1
```

In Java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh test.sh \"pacmd list-source-outputs\"");
```

Here is the official answer from Jetbrains:

> How do you launch IDE: from terminal via .sh script or from desktop
>   launcher? make sure to try to launch it from terminal via .sh script.
>
> Also try restarting the IDE after starting the pulseaudio or restart
>   the pulseaudio daemon in IDE terminal. Try also these suggestions:
>   https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1214072#p1214072
>   https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1214157#p1214157
>
> Note that after changing the environment it might be needed to restart
>   the IDE.