# Java ProcessBuilder how to get binary output from command

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to use execute a command using ProcessBuilder. The command is supposed to write binary data on stdout. How can I get this data in my byte[] ?

Comment: Read from `process.getInputStream()`, the same as with text output?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example that returns `true` for output `1` and `false` for output `0`, (throws Exception in all other cases). I also added setting a working path and an environment variable, which is not required for your particular example so you can delete it.

1. You can copy paste this code as a class, compile it to jar and run it.
2. It is verified in WSL Ubuntu 16.04.
3. Setting the workdirectory is verified by setting `binaryCommand[0]="touch";`and `binaryCommand[1]="1";`, re-compiling and running the `.jar` file.

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.StringJoiner;

   public class GenerateOutput {

       /**
        * This code can execute a command and return the binary value of it's output if it 
        * is actually binary.
        * 
        * compile this project into a .jar and run it with for example:
        * java -jar readOutputOfCommand.jar
        * 
        * @param args
        * @throws Exception 
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           boolean answerYes = false; // no yes answer to any command prompts is needed.

           // to execute a command with spaces in it in terminal, put them in an array of Strings.
           String[] binaryCommand = new String[2];

           // write a command that gives a binary output:
           binaryCommand[0] = "echo";
           binaryCommand[1] = "1";

           // pass the commands to a method that executes them
           System.out.println("The output of the echo command = "+executeCommands(binaryCommand,answerYes));
       }

       /**
        * This executes the commands in terminal. 
        * Additionally it sets an environment variable (not necessary for your particular solution)
        * Additionally it sets a working path (not necessary for your particular solution)
        * @param commandData
        * @param ansYes
        * @throws Exception 
        */
       public static boolean executeCommands(String[] commands,Boolean ansYes) throws Exception {
           String capturedCommandOutput = null;
           System.out.println("Incoming commandData = "+Arrays.deepToString(commands));
           File workingDirectory = new File("/mnt/c/testfolder b/");

           // create a ProcessBuilder to execute the commands in
           ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);

           // this is not necessary but can be used to set an environment variable for the command
           processBuilder = setEnvironmentVariable(processBuilder); 

           // this is not necessary but can be used to set the working directory for the command
           processBuilder.directory(workingDirectory);

           // execute the actual commands
           try {

                Process process = processBuilder.start();

                // capture the output stream of the command
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
               StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
               reader.lines().iterator().forEachRemaining(sj::add);
               capturedCommandOutput = sj.toString();
               System.out.println("The output of this command ="+ capturedCommandOutput);

                // here you connect the output of your command to any new input, e.g. if you get prompted for `yes`
                new Thread(new SyncPipe(process.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
                new Thread(new SyncPipe(process.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
               PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());

               //This is not necessary but can be used to answer yes to being prompted
               if (ansYes) {
                   System.out.println("WITH YES!");
               stdin.println("yes");
               }

               // write any other commands you want here

               stdin.close();

               // this lets you know whether the command execution led to an error(!=0), or not (=0).
               int returnCode = process.waitFor();
               System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
           return retrieveBooleanOutput(capturedCommandOutput);
       }

       private static boolean retrieveBooleanOutput(String commandOutput) throws Exception {
           if (commandOutput != null && commandOutput.length() == 1) { 
               if (commandOutput.contains("0")) {
                   return false;
               } else if (commandOutput.contains("1")) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
           throw new Exception("The output is not binary.");
       }

       /**
        * source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369664/using-export-in-java
        * @param processBuilder
        * @param varName
        * @param varContent
        * @return
        */
       private static ProcessBuilder setEnvironmentVariable(ProcessBuilder processBuilder){
           String varName = "variableName";
           String varContent = "/mnt/c/testfolder a/";

           Map<String, String> env = processBuilder.environment();
            System.out.println("Setting environment variable "+varName+"="+varContent);
            env.put(varName, varContent);

            processBuilder.environment().put(varName, varContent);

            return processBuilder;
       }
   }


   class SyncPipe implements Runnable
   {   
       /**
        * This class pipes the output of your command to any new input you generated
        * with stdin. For example, suppose you run cp /mnt/c/a.txt /mnt/b/
        * but for some reason you are prompted: "do you really want to copy there yes/no?
        * then you can answer yes since your input is piped to the output of your
        * original command. (At least that is my practical interpretation might be wrong.)
        * @param istrm
        * @param ostrm
        */
       public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
           istrm_ = istrm;
           ostrm_ = ostrm;
       }
       public void run() {

         try
         {
             final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
             {
                 ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);                
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         private final OutputStream ostrm_;
         private final InputStream istrm_;
   }
   ```