# How to get path to the temp folder from native code on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

`getenv("TMPDIR")` returns `NULL`. Any suggestions on what is temp folder/where to create one?

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595324/creating-temporary-files-in-android-with-ndk , which seems to address the exact problem that you have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know there is no global /tmp in Android, you should use the **cache** dir.

Use `getCacheDir()` to get the "**tmp**" dir.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal and 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29