# How to use environment variables with android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, environment-variables

I'm a new app developer and i need to store variables in **environment variables**.

Because some of variables have sensitive info.
So guys i need to know how to use **environment variables** with **android studio** in details?

I searched a lot about it but i couldn't find much details.

**Update:** I need to store string values in the environment variables

Comment: See if that one helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597058/android-setget-environmental-variables-in-java

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - what are you trying to do with these environment variables?

Comment: @RyanMentley I have variables in my project need to be hidden if i will deploy the project in github, so i heard that with environment variables i can manage that but i'm asking how

Comment: Please describe the types of variables and what you're using them for.  The answer depends on what you're using them for.

Comment: @RyanMentley I need to store string values.