# How do I put a variable into environment thru Java program?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

I know, I can get a variable from environment by System.getenv, but how do I put a variable into environment in java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Environment is associated with each process in the system and is inherited by a child process from the parent process. Every process can read and modify its own environment and it can prepare environment to be passed to a child process. For example, you cannot put variables into the shell/cmd.exe from which you launched your JVM from within the JVM.

In order to put a variable into the environment of a process you're about to execute you can use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).