# Using PowerMock to mock System.class in multiple tests not working as expected

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

Class under test:

```java
public class SystemCaller {
  public String callSystem() {
    return System.getenv("test-this");
  }
}
```

Test 1:

```java
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SystemCaller.class, System.class})
public class SystemTestOne {

    @Before
    public void start() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.getenv("test-this")).thenReturn("hello-one");
    }

    @After
    public void stop() {}

    @Test
    public void verifySystemTestOne() throws Exception {
        assertThat(new SystemCaller().callSystem(), is("hello-one"));
    }
}
```

Test 2:

```java
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SystemCaller.class, System.class})
public class SystemTestTwo {

    @Before
    public void start() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.getenv("test-this")).thenReturn("hello-two");
    }

    @After
    public void stop() {}

    @Test
    public void verifySystemTestTwo() throws Exception {
        assertThat(new SystemCaller().callSystem(), is("hello-two"));
    }
}
```

If run individually, each test passes on its own. However, when I run *all* tests, the tests fail. And the error varies. Sometimes, the assertion expects `hello-two`, but gets `hello-one`. At other times, `callSystem()` just returns `null`!

Is there a setup issue here? Or, is this because I'm mocking a `static` method (on `System` class in this case) that's causing the issue?

My dependencies:

```
      "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.5" ::
      "com.squareup.okhttp3" % "okhttp" % "3.6.0" ::
      "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.0" ::
      "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test->default" ::
      "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test" ::
      "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-core" % "1.3" % "test" ::
      "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-library" % "1.3.RC2" % "test" ::
      "com.squareup.okhttp3" % "mockwebserver" % "3.8.0" % "test" ::
      "org.powermock" % "powermock-core" % "1.6.6" % "test" ::
      "org.powermock" % "powermock-api-mockito" % "1.6.6" % "test" ::
      "org.powermock" % "powermock-module-junit4" % "1.6.6" % "test" ::
```

**UPDATE 1:**

OK, the suggestion from [@kevin-welker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433348/kevin-welker), to use `EnvironmentVariables` actually worked. However, I'm seeing a weird issue where, when I run the JUnit tests from Intellij IDEA (using *JUnit Run Configuration*), everything works, but when I run them via `sbt` (thru `./sbt test`) they fail with the same error :(.

I'm leveraging https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface to run these tests, but can't seem to get them to work.

**UPDATE 2:**

Alright! Thanks to [@kevin-welker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433348/kevin-welker) and [@stefan-birkner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557091/stefan-birkner), I got the tests to work as expected! Since there's only a handful of tests I need to run, and they're really fast, I'm OK losing out on the parallelism!

Comment: Does `sbt` run your tests in parallel? Then this problem is possible because the map that stores the environment variables is a singleton.

Comment: @StefanBirkner . . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899723/how-to-turn-off-parallel-execution-of-tests-for-multi-project-builds solved it 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a micro library to help with mocking system classes called [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/).  Use is as simple as

```
@Rule
public final ProvideSystemProperty myPropertyHasMyValue
    = new ProvideSystemProperty("MyProperty", "MyValue");
```

Comment: Same error when using `EnvironmentVariables`. One test passed, the other failed:

[error] Test SystemTestOne.verifySystemTestOne failed: 
[error] Expected: is "hello-one"
[error]      but: was "hello-two"
[error] Failed: Total 2, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 1, Skipped 0
[error] Failed tests:
[error]  SystemTestOne
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful

Comment: are you doing the `environmentVariables.set()` in the @Before as in your OP examples, or are you doing that in the test method as shown in the System Rules examples?

Comment: In the `@Before` method. Should I move it to the `test()` method?

Comment: Moved `env.set(...)` to the `test()` method, but got the same error.

Comment: Kevin, please see my update. Your suggestion actually worked, but I'm not able to get it to pass when running the tests via `sbt test`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock `System` and other system classes. That's usually why you create wrappers like your `SystemCaller` class that will only contains the untestable logic and that you can mock where they are used in the code.

More info here: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System

Comment: I was following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290503/having-trouble-mocking-system-getenv-calls-in-junit to mock `System.class`. Are you saying that solution is incorrect?

Comment: Yes this solution is incorrect as you cannot prepare for test System.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(System.class);` after your test (@After or @AfterClass), it should reset the mock of System.class.

Comment: Tried that, no dice.