# Properly set (system) properties in JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit, junit5

We are using an approach similar to [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) to handle (system) properties in our JUnit 4 tests. The main reason for this is to clean up the environment after each test, so that other tests do not inadvertently depend on possible side effects.

Since JUnit 5 is released, I wonder if there is a "JUnit 5 way" of doing this?

Comment: JUnit5 in general nowadays has one answer for everything, it looks like - [extension API](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions). I haven't played with it myself, but most things I think can be expressed with it. That said, JUnit4 way should still be perfectly viable for what you want.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks for the hint, will have a look at the extension model.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is [JUnit Pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org/), a "JUnit 5 extension pack". It comes with `@ClearSystemProperty` and `@SetSystemProperty`. From the [docs](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/system-properties/#clearsystemproperty-and-setsystemproperty):

> The `@ClearSystemProperty` and `@SetSystemProperty` annotations can be used to clear and set, respectively, the values of system properties for a test execution. Both annotations work on the test method and class level, are repeatable, combinable, and inherited from higher-level containers. After the annotated method has been executed, the properties mentioned in the annotation will be restored to their original value or the value of the higher-level container, or will be cleared if they didn’t have one before. Other system properties that are changed during the test, are not restored […]

Example:

```java
@Test
@ClearSystemProperty(key = "some key")
@SetSystemProperty(key = "another key", value = "new value")
void test() {
    assertNull(System.getProperty("some key"));
    assertEquals("new value", System.getProperty("another key"));
}
```

If you don't know your values at compile time and/or want to parameterize a system properties test, you can use `@RestoreSystemProperties` (since v2.1.0). From the [docs](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/system-properties/#restoresystemproperties):

> `@RestoreSystemProperties` can be used to restore changes to system properties made directly in code. While `@ClearSystemProperty` and `@SetSystemProperty` set or clear specific properties and values, they don’t allow property values to be calculated or parameterized, thus there are times you may want to directly set properties in your test code. `@RestoreSystemProperties` can be placed on test methods or test classes and will completely restore all system properties to their original state after a test or test class is complete.

Example:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = { "new value", "newer value" })
@RestoreSystemProperties
void parameterizedTest(String value) {
    System.setProperty("some key", value);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It does not work with Java 17 due to restrictions with the system module.

Comment: @AnatolyYakimchuk could it be you are confusing system properties and environment variables? The former shouldn't yield any warnings/errors, for the latter there is [this section](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/environment-variables/#warnings-for-reflective-access) in the Pioneer docs.

Comment: I ended up using System Stubs library https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs it does correctly set env variables even with the new (17+) version of Java.

Comment: I gave a +1 to @AnatolyYakimchuk 's comment just above mine.  The System Stubs library is what worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [extension API](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions). You could create an annotation which defines your extension to a test method.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@ExtendWith(SystemPropertyExtension.class)
public @interface SystemProperty {

    String key();

    String value();
}
```

Then, you can create the extension class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;

public class SystemPropertyExtension implements AfterEachCallback, BeforeEachCallback {

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        SystemProperty annotation = extensionContext.getTestMethod().get().getAnnotation(SystemProperty.class);
        System.clearProperty(annotation.key());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        SystemProperty annotation = extensionContext.getTestMethod().get().getAnnotation(SystemProperty.class);
        System.setProperty(annotation.key(), annotation.value());
    }
}
```

Finally, you can annotate your test with properties:

```
@Test
@SystemProperty(key = "key", value = "value")
void testPropertey() {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("key"));
}
```

This solution supports only one system property for each test. If you want to support multiple test, you could use a nested annotation and the extension could handle this as well:

```
@Test
@SystemProperties({
    @SystemProperty(key = "key1", value = "value"),
    @SystemProperty(key = "key2", value = "value")
})
void testPropertey() {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("key1"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("key2"));
}
```

Comment: It's JUnit5, so it is Java8, and so it has repeatable annotations, and there's really no need to expose `@SystemProperties` annotation to user - just mark `@SystemProperty` as repeatable and call `getAnnotationS` instead of `getAnnotation`.

Comment: will not work for by hitting the System.getenv() from the code,,

Comment: @ses system properties != environment variables. If you have to deal with the latter, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63494695/3429133

Answer (score 4):

The JUnit Pioneer way requires the system properties to be known at compile time. Where they are generated at runtime, say via `Testcontainers` or `Wiremock` creating things on random ports, it may be better to use something which can be driven from dynamic values.

The problem can be solved with System Stubs https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs which provides JUnit 5 and is a fork of the code from System Lambda, itself built by the author of System Rules.

```java
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)
class SomeTest {
    // can be initialised here with some up front properties
    // or leave like this for auto initialization
    @SystemStub
    private SystemProperties someProperties;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        someProperties.set("prop1", "value1")
            .set("prop2", "value2");
    }

    @Test
    void someTest() {
        // properties are set here
        // and can also call System.setProperty


        // properties reset to state before the test case ran
        // as the test case is tidied up
    }
}
```

Comment: One can use Pioneer's `@ClearSystemProperty` and then `System#setProperty(...)` for non-constant expressions, so values don't need to be known at compile time (see [docs](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/system-properties/)).

Comment: True. As `System.setProperty` is a pretty easy thing to use, it's not a big deal per-se. However, what's nice about the above is that the set of System properties can be defined in the `SystemProperties` object at construction, or in the `Before` method, and is not yet applied to the properties until the test runs.

Even better is the `EnvironmentVariables` alternative from SystemStubs, which does the same for the harder-to-reach environment variables.