# How to fully test coverage a constructor that has a System.getenv("name") operation inside

Tags: java, junit, junit5, test-coverage

I am using JUNIT5, have been trying to fully coverage a piece of code that involves System.getenv(""); I writed a couple classes to replicate what I am experiencing right now and so you can use them to understand me also (**minimal reproducible example**):

First we have the service I need to get with full coverage (**ServiceToTest.class**) (it has a CustomContainer object which contains methods that it needs):

```
@Service
public class ServiceToTest {

    private final CustomContainer customContainer;

    public ServiceToTest() {
        Object configuration = new Object();
        String envWord = System.getenv("envword");
        this.customContainer = new CustomContainer(configuration, envWord == null ? "default" : envWord);

    }

    public String getContainerName() {
        return customContainer.getContainerName();
    }

}
```

**CustomContainer.class:**

```
public class CustomContainer {
    @Getter
    String containerName;
    Object configuration;

    public CustomContainer(Object configuration, String containerName) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.containerName = containerName;
    }

}
```

I have tried using ReflectionTestUtils to set the envWord variable without success... I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/496849/12085680, also tried using @SystemStubsExtension https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892484/12085680, and finally I also tried using Spy like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31029944/12085680

But the problem is that this variable is inside the constructor so this only executes once and I think that it happens before any of this configs I tried before can apply, here is my **test class**:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestService {
    // I have to mock this becase in real project it has methods which I need mocked behavour
    private static CustomContainer mockCustomContainer = mock(CustomContainer.class);
    // The serviceToTest class in which I use ReflectionTestUtils to use the mock above
    // Here is where the constructor gets called and it happens BEFORE (debuged) the setup method
    // which is anotated with @BeforeAll
    private static ServiceToTest serviceToTest = new ServiceToTest();

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        // set the field customContainer at serviceToTest class to mockCustomContainer
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serviceToTest, "customContainer", mockCustomContainer);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetContainerNameNotNull() {
        assertNull(serviceToTest.getContainerName());
    }

}
```

I need to write a test in which serviceToTest.getContainerName is not null but the real purpose of this is to have coverage of this sentence `envWord == null ? "default" : envWord` so it would be a test that is capable of executing the constructor and mocking System.getenv() so that it returns not null...

Right now the coverage looks like this and I can not find a way to **make it 100%** Any ideas??

[image: coverage]

**EDIT:**
So after following tgdavies suggestion, the code can be 100% covered, so this is the way:

**Interface CustomContainerFactory:**

```
public interface CustomContainerFactory {
    CustomContainer create(Object configuration, String name);
}
```

**CustomContainerFactoryImpl:**

```
@Service
public class CustomContainerFactoryImpl implements CustomContainerFactory {

    @Override
    public CustomContainer create(Object configuration, String name) {
        return new CustomContainer(configuration, name);
    }

}
```

**EnvironmentAccessor Interface:**

```
public interface EnvironmentAccessor {
    String getEnv(String name);
}
```

**EnvironmentAccessorImpl:**

```
@Service
public class EnvironmentAccessorImpl implements EnvironmentAccessor {

    @Override
    public String getEnv(String name) {
        return System.getenv(name);
    }

}
```

**Class ServiceToTest after refactoring:**

```
@Service
public class ServiceToTest {

    private final CustomContainer customContainer;
    
    public ServiceToTest(EnvironmentAccessor environmentAccessor, CustomContainerFactory customContainerFactory) {
        Object configuration = new Object();
        String envWord = environmentAccessor.getEnv("anything");
        this.customContainer = customContainerFactory.create(configuration, envWord == null ? "default" : envWord);

    }

    public String getContainerName() {
        return customContainer.getContainerName();
    }

}
```

**Finally the test case after refactoring (here is were I think it can be improved maybe?):**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestService {

    private static CustomContainer mockCustomContainer = mock(CustomContainer.class);
    private static CustomContainerFactory customContainerFactoryMock = mock(CustomContainerFactoryImpl.class);
    private static EnvironmentAccessor environmentAccessorMock = mock(EnvironmentAccessorImpl.class);

    private static ServiceToTest serviceToTest;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        when(environmentAccessorMock.getEnv(anyString())).thenReturn("hi");
        serviceToTest = new ServiceToTest(environmentAccessorMock, customContainerFactoryMock);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serviceToTest, "customContainer", mockCustomContainer);
        when(serviceToTest.getContainerName()).thenReturn("hi");
    }

    @Test
    void testGetContainerNameNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(serviceToTest.getContainerName());
    }

    @Test
    void coverNullReturnFromGetEnv() {
        when(environmentAccessorMock.getEnv(anyString())).thenReturn(null);
        assertAll(() -> new ServiceToTest(environmentAccessorMock, customContainerFactoryMock));
    }

}
```

Now the **coverage** is 100%:

[image: coverage100]

**EDIT 2:**

We can improve the test class and get the same 100% coverage like so:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestService {

    private static CustomContainer mockCustomContainer = mock(CustomContainer.class);
    private static IContainerFactory customContainerFactoryMock = mock(ContainerFactoryImpl.class);
    private static IEnvironmentAccessor environmentAccessorMock = mock(EnvironmentAccessorImpl.class);

    private static ServiceToTest serviceToTest;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        when(environmentAccessorMock.getEnv(anyString())).thenReturn("hi");
        when(customContainerFactoryMock.create(any(), anyString())).thenReturn(mockCustomContainer);
        serviceToTest = new ServiceToTest(environmentAccessorMock, customContainerFactoryMock);

    }

    @Test
    void testGetContainerNameNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(serviceToTest.getContainerName());
    }

    @Test
    void coverNullReturnFromGetEnv() {
        when(environmentAccessorMock.getEnv(anyString())).thenReturn(null);
        assertAll(() -> new ServiceToTest(environmentAccessorMock, customContainerFactoryMock));
    }

}
```

Comment: If what you're trying to do is just ensure each branch is covered then what about refactoring the valueOrDefault check in line 13 into a utility method and testing that separately ... then the line 13 will be 100% covered.  Of course if what you really want is to test what happens with the different versions of custom container in the service then you will need to have 2 different tests or configurations in the test..

Comment: *How* is but the form following the function of *why*. So *why* do you want 100% of coverage?

Comment: Create another component for accessing environment variables, which you can mock.

Comment: @tgdavies Could you show in an answer how can it be achieved? But I wonder if I do that, this new component will not be 100% covered? Because this System.getenv() will now go into it

Comment: @Turing85 I need it because I need a % of coverage in order to be able to submit merge request and also why not have coverage of something

Comment: "Coverage of something" doesn't sound like a good metric for code quality. Coverage of relevant business logic sounds much more sensible.

Comment: @MrR I am sorry I did not really understand the suggestion, if I execute the tests setting the environment variable then it will not be null, but now the branch of it being null will not be covered :/

Comment: @BugsOverflow - you can use the idea suggested by tgdavies answer, or if it doesn't actually matter what the specific value is - then move the valueOrDefault selection code into a new static method you can tests to 100% (both ways - branch coverage), and then you get 100% method coverage in the constructor because there is no longer a branch in the constructor.

Comment: `when(serviceToTest.getContainerName()).thenReturn("hi");` does nothing, because `serviceToTest` is not a mock. You want to mock that method on `mockCustomContainer`. You don't need to use `ReflectionTestUtils` -- get `customContainerFactoryMock` to return `mockCustomContainer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your code to make it testable, by moving object creation and static method calls to components, which you can mock in your tests:

```java
interface ContainerFactory {
    CustomContainer create(Object configuration, String name);
}

interface EnvironmentAccessor {
    String getEnv(String name);
}

@Service
public class ServiceToTest {

    private final CustomContainer customContainer;

    public ServiceToTest(ContainerFactory containerFactory, EnvironmentAccessor environmentAccessor) {
        Object configuration = new Object();
        String envWord = environmentAccessor.getEnv("envword");
        this.customContainer = containerFactory.create(configuration, envWord == null ? "default" : envWord);
    }

    public String getContainerName() {
        return customContainer.getContainerName();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, appreciate it, but I have a question, this will make the EnvironmentAccesor implementation miss the branch also? Because I will move the System.getenv() to it, and now I need to coverage this implementation also

Comment: There's no branch in `EnvironmentAccessorImpl.getEnv`.

Comment: Hey, would appreciate if you could add how would the Test class look like, because I manage to make it work this way that you suggested, but im not sure if it was suppose to be made like I did it... I will share in a few moments in the EDIT of the question (with also how the Impl of the interfaces was made)

Comment: Review my question edit now pls