# Use system variable in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, macos, spring-boot

I have defined a variable in my .bash_profile like this :

```
export PROFILE=local
```

Now, I want to get this value in my spring boot application to load different configuration files according to this value.

To do this, I used the annotation @Value but spring can't resolve the value of profile :

```
@Value("${profile}")
private String environment;
```

What have I missed ?

EDIT : 
This code is launched from a JUnit test inside Eclipse (launched as desktop application)

Comment: did you try `${PROFILE}`

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work !

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168884/how-to-test-code-dependent-on-environment-variables-using-junit

Answer (score 0):

You should add `spring.profiles.active: ENV_NAME` in your properties file. Or you can pass it from command line using `-Dspring.profiles.active=ENV_NAME` .

EDIT:

You can also use `Map<String, String> getenv = System.getenv();` to get all the environment variables in your code. Then you'll have access to all env variables.

Comment: I don't want to have application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties... because I don't want that api keys or other critical information are on our git repo.

Comment: You can use `jasypt` to encrypt values in properties file. Or you can any way send the same `profile` name through command prompt using `-Dprofile=ENV_NAME` and get it using `@Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of  this  `Environment` class.

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;
```

and then

```
String profile = ((StandardServletEnvironment) environment).getSystemEnvironment().get("PROFILE").toString();
```

Comment: It returns a null value :/

Comment: System properties and environment variables are two different things!