# jar file execution from cmd prompt

Tags: java, jar

I thoroughly checked this one, and the standard answers aren't working for me.

Whenever I try to execute a jar file from cmd prompt, instead of opening the jar file it opens a new window of Dr. Java.

I've used DrJava's "Create custom drjava jar" to create a jar file called "TestJar.jar", including:

Manifest.txt:

Main-Class: com.package.name.TestJar 
Class-Path: algs4.jar

TestJar.java:

```
public class TestJar
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  System.out.println("Hello");  
  StdOut.println("hello StdOut");
 }

}
```

I type this in the cmd prompt:

```
java -jar TestJar.jar
```

And DrJava opens a new window.  Any ideas?  I've tried creating the jar file from cmd prompt but all commands I type starting with "jar" get this error:

> 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...I'm pretty new to Java.

Comment: With the standard JRE, you need syntax like `java -jar TestJar.jar TestJar`.  ALSO: If "jar is not recognized...", then it sounds like you need to add your Java directory to the %PATH% ;)

Comment: Also make sure to have Main-Class and Class-Path on separate lines. And don't forget to press an enter after the last line in manifest file (to get a proper EOL).

Comment: @paulsm4 Using the syntax java -jar TestJar.jar TestJar it doesn't do anything...no error messages, but nor does it open an instance of DrJava either.  All the main method is doing is system.out.println().  I should see that in the command prompt, right?

Comment: @Usman, thanks but I did those things.  The commenter here doesn't save line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the `jar` program is not in your `%PATH%`. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358265/how-to-update-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd-windows) helpful.

Comment: I've tried adding various things to the PATH variable.  But I actually can't find the jar program on my computer.  Is it jar.exe?

Comment: @EricWalton Yes, it's `jar.exe`. Do you know where `java.exe` is? The `jar.exe` program should be in the same folder.

Comment: `java.exe` is also placed in `C:\Windows\System32`, if I recall correctly, but there is a `java.exe` in the installation directory's `bin` folder. Try looking for a folder like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_[version]\bin`. It would be in `Program Files (x86)` if you have the 32 bit version.

Comment: Thanks, guys, but I stil can't find it.  I found two paths that look promising:
C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin and 
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin

Both have the java application, neither has the jar.exe file.  Do I need to reinstall something?  I'd hate to, as everything else with java works fine.

Comment: the `jar` program is part of the JDK, not the JRE, and it's used *only* to create / modify / test jars, not to run them.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up being part of the solution.  Eventually was able to point to teh jar  from cmd line, but only after setting the path variable.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I appreciate your coming back to this question many days later and accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Java determines the location of the `main` function using a [manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). If you unzip your jar file, you'll see the manifest file in a META-INF folder. (A jar file is just a zip file with a different extension and some specific files inside.)

You'll need an entry like this in your manifest:

```
Main-Class: packagename.classname
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more details about setting the location of `main`.

To control the manifest in Dr. Java, I think you will need to create a custom manifest. [This source](http://drjava.org/index.php?page=docs/user/ch04.html) provides these instructions:

> For more control over the properties of the jar, you may enter a
>   custom manifest by selecting "Custom Manifest" and pressing the "Edit
>   Manifest" button.

Comment: Here's the manifest file I included:  Main-Class: com.package.name.TestJar   Is that the wrong syntax?  I'm not sure what the package name would be.

Comment: You have to declare the package and set up the folder structure to match: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html So if you want your code in a package named `mypack`, create a folder named `mypack`, put the TestJar.java code file inside the folder, and put the statement `package mypack` at the very top of the code file. Non-packaged code files are unsupported in Java 7. Then your manifest should have `Main-Class: mypack.TestJar`. You may have to fiddle around with Dr. Java to make the package work, but the `mypack` folder should be alongside META-INF in the jar file.

Comment: I just tried that.  it didn't make a difference.  What fiddling with DrJava do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

1) To run your test jar from a Windows command:

> a) Make sure Java is installed on your PC
>
> b) Set your %JAVA_HOME% (EX: set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program files\java\jre7)
>
> c) Update your %PATH%  (EX: PATH=c:\Program
>   files\java\jre7\bin;%PATH%)
>
> d) Invoke program with "java -jar JARFILE MAIN-CLASS (EX: java -jar
>   TestJar.jar TestJar)

2) To run DrJava .jar on Windows, I would just double-click on the .jar file from Windows Explorer

3) To test and debug your program, I would just use DrJava (instead of from the command line).

4) You do *NOT* need "jar.exe" installed to run a .jar file.  You only need it to view, modify or create a .jar.  jar.exe comes with the Java JDK.

5) I suspect you probably *WILL* need the Java JDK to build or debug any programs with DrJava, however.

Here's a good link on running .jar files from Windows, if you need more help:

- http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-.Jar-Java-File