# Rcpp can't find Rtools: "Error 1 occurred building shared library"

Tags: r, rcpp

I am running into a simple setup problem with Rcpp and I cannot get it to work. I tried to follow this example http://www.r-bloggers.com/user2013-the-rcpp-tutorial/ 
But when executing this code:

```
library(Rcpp)
evalCpp("1 + 1", showOutput= TRUE)
```

I get this output

```
C:/R/R-30~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB -o "sourceCpp_33280.dll" "file8d01b0a675b.cpp" 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. 
Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
```

I have done the following things in an attempt to make it work:

- installed Rtools 31 with install.Rtools()
- installed R in C:\R\R-3.0.1
- library files are stored in C:\R\R-3.0.1\library
- installed Rstudio in C:\R\RStudio
- placed my script in C:\R

most similar issues seem to suggest that a space was in the file path, therefore i moved pretty much everything I could. But still it fails to locate Rtools. I tried it on my laptop and on my desktop and both don't work, so there is probably something structural I am doing wrong.

Comment: You may need to reboot after installing Rtools so that the changes to your path will take effect.

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it. How silly. Thanks :)

Comment: Setting the path by hand in a new `cmd.exe` session also works.

Comment: Perhaps we should have a test function, e.g. `Rcpp::ready()` instead of `evalCpp( "1+1" )`.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like neither your R binaries nor Rtools directories are in your system's `PATH` environment variable. Try this:

```r
> writeLines(strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1L]])
C:\R\Rtools\bin
C:\R\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin
C:\R\R-devel\bin\x64
[... and so on ...]
```

If your directories `C:\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\` and `C:\R\Rtools\bin\` & `C:\R\Rtools\gcc-*.*.*\bin\` (replace \gcc-*-*-*\ with your version of the gcc-binaries) are not listed, the needed components can't be found.
To be on the safe side, also create a system variable called `CYGWIN` with the value `nodosfilewarning`.

After changing/creating the `PATH` and `CYGWIN` variables, reboot. Then it should work and you can place your sources *anywhere* on your machine and also compile them manually using `R CMD SHLIB`.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. As Dirk suggested in the comments to the question, updating path in cmd.exe (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358265/how-to-update-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd-windows) helped `find_rtools()` from `devtools` to succeed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r

Comment: Since R3.3 an additional variable must be set, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44035904/4468078