# Why do I need to run find_rtools() before has_devel() = TRUE?

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools

I try to follow the guide in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html to understand Rcpp
but I always need to run `devtools::find_rtools()` before any Rcpp function works:
If I do

```
library(devtools)
library(Rcpp)

has_devel() # Error: Command failed(1)

# Example from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html
add <- cppFunction('int add(int x, int y, int z) {
  int sum = x + y + z;
  return sum;
}')
```

I get an error and Rstudio prompts me to install additional build tools (but nothing happens when I say yes). It looks like some make command fails, but `system("where make")` gives a path that is in my PATH.
When I then do

```
find_rtools() # True

has_devel() # True

# Try the example again
add <- cppFunction('int add(int x, int y, int z) {
   int sum = x + y + z;
   return sum;
}')
# Now works
add(1,2,3) # 6
```

both devtools and Rcpp seem to be happy. Why is that and how can I fix that?

Here is the start of my PATH

```
path <- get_path()
head(path, 8)

[1] "F:\\Software\\R-3.3.0\\bin\\x64"
"F:\\Software\\Rtools\\bin"                    
[3] "F:\\Software\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin"
"F:\\Software\\Python 3\\Scripts\\"            
[5] "F:\\Software\\Python 3\\"
"F:\\Software\\Rtools\\bin"                    
[7] "F:\\Software\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin"
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\"
```

Comment: Is that path from a clean R session? `find_rtools()` modifies your path for that session only. If you want this to work permanently without having to run devtools, change your path via the environment variables dialog (in the Windows Start menu).

Comment: Yes, that is from a clean session. 
But which directory is missing from the path, Rtools seems to have at least some directories in it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you did not put the rtools install location on the system `PATH` variable. So, `devtools::find_rtools()` is [scanning the registry and adding it](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/b1564c2f5d25bcc0d92ce2dd82431702125dce53/R/rtools.r#L89-L133). The addition is only valid for the active session.

Now, the `devtools::has_devel()` is a [very simple build and link of a C++ file](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/e29d528474d29d9fad0c73775d4a8d03993db956/R/has-devel.r#L22-L37). Thus, running `devtools::has_devel()` without the necessary environment (e.g. a valid rtools install) will yield a failure.  In this case, the environment simply is not setup right as the system `PATH` variable has not been modified.

Make sure the following are in your system path variable:

`C:\Rtools\bin` and `C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin`

Check within a clean R session:

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

Comment: Hm ok, well I have `F:\\Software\\Rtools\\bin` and `F:\\Software\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin` in the path when I look it up in R as you told me to and they show up in Windows settings as well. Is it a problem to not have Rtools in `C:\`?

Comment: I would suggest that you uninstall `Rtools`, clean out your `PATH` variable from the previous install and delete any old R installations, [download a new copy](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools33.exe), and then [install it](https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/Rintro/Rwinpack.html).

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r

Comment: Tried that as well now, still doesn't work.Here is the error code I still get: `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"F:/Software/R-3.3.0/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc: not found
make: *** [foo.o] Error 127`
Noob question but why is it trying to find stuff on C instead of in the path in F?

Comment: So, either you didn't clean your `PATH` variable or when installing `rtools` the addition of the different locations to your `PATH` variable where not correct. Regardless, please **clean** the `PATH` variable of `rtools` and try the install again but pay close attention to the "add to PATH" step.