# Can't use Rcpp engine in R Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rcpp, devtools

I tried to `Knit HTML` the following Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Florian Privé"
date: "12 septembre 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r fibCpp, engine='Rcpp'}
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fibonacci(const int x) {
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return(x);
    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}
```
````

I got the following error:

```
Building shared library for Rcpp code chunk...
Warning message:
l'exécution de la commande 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_2.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="file110c1d4643e9.o"' renvoie un statut 127 


Quitting from lines 11-18 (test.Rmd) 
Error in (function (file = "", code = NULL, env = globalenv(), embeddedR = TRUE,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... block_exec -> in_dir -> engine -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Exécution arrêtée
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Is it a problem related to Windows?

#### Environment Information from `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_1.5    rsconnect_0.4.3 htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.1     yaml_2.1.13    
 [6] Rcpp_0.12.7     stringi_1.1.1   rmarkdown_1.0   stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.10  
[11] evaluate_0.9
```

#### Rtools install check via `devtools::find_rtools()`

```
[1] TRUE
```

#### Results from `Sys.getenv()['PATH']`

```
## PATH                  C:\Program
##                       Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
##                       Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
##                       Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\bin;C:\Program
##                       Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
##                       Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\libnvvp;;C:\Program Files
##                       (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program
##                       Files\Intel\iCLS
##                       Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
##                       Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
##                       Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
##                       Components\DAL;C:\Program
##                       Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
##                       Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
##                       (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
##                       Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
##                       (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
##                       Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
##                       (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Florian\.dnx\bin;C:\Program
##                       Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files
##                       (x86)\NVIDIA
##                       Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Florian\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Florian\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Florian\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program
##                       Files
##                       (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\client;C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32
```

Comment: Only have time to note that your Rcpp example works fine on macOS, latest RStudio Preview, super-current Rcpp and R 3.3.1

Comment: Sorry, I can't edit my post due to too much code in it apparently.
You can get the results of `Sys.getenv()['PATH']` [there](https://privefl.github.io/R-presentation/system-env.html).
Moreover, I opened an other project and `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")` is working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the requested information of the [`Sys.getenv['PATH']`](https://privefl.github.io/R-presentation/system-env.html) not containing a path with `Rtools` in it and the knowledge that the `knitr` error is being triggered by an invalid *engine* path, I think you are falling victim to [devtools::find_rtools()](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/5d4d6d55c2c0ba4ebbe797a95459f8cd5e5f400f/R/rtools.r#L89-L109) throwing a false positive on setup.

This is typically the case since if it is unable to find [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) on the system path, it scans for [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) within the registry and then sets an environment flag. The environment flag does not typically persist while running rmarkdown or during the package build stage. Also see: [Why do I need to run find_rtools() before has_devel() = TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226661/why-do-i-need-to-run-find-rtools-before-has-devel-true)

E.g. If you close all open session *R* sessions, then open a **new** R session and only type `Rcpp::evalCpp("2 + 2")` you will likely trigger a compile error.

The fix for this is simple: **Add the [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) install location to the `PATH` system variable.** I maintain an installation guide that literally takes you step-by-step through this process here: http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp/install-rtools-for-rcpp/

As of Rtools 3.4, the two locations that must be added to the `PATH` are:

```
c:\Rtools\bin;
c:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;
```

To modify your `PATH` variable on windows see either:

- [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)
- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Answer (score 2):

I also just experienced this issue. I see that it's been a couple years since this was last addressed, so I wanted to update with the solution that I've found in 2020.

I received that exact error that was mentioned at the top, and had into do a fresh install of Rtools. I originally had RBuildTools, which works for other packages I've built, but still had the issue when compiling the cpp code for this project. I installed Rtools40 and kept all of the defaults. Then changed the system path variable on my windows 10 machine to say `C:\rtools40\usr\bin`. After restarting the machine, knitr rendered the document without any further errors.

Rtools40 installation instructions can [be found at this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

I hope that this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error today on windows 10, and the outputs you included are as good as identical to those of mine.

Neither J_F's workaround or adding "c:\Rtools\bin" to paths through advanced system settings solved it.

What solved it for me was to uninstall Rtools and reinstall it, checking the option to change the paths during installation. I put the paths: "c:\Rtools\bin", "C:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin", "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\i386" and "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64" in there.

I wonder why adding "c:\Rtools\bin" to paths through advanced system settings didnt change the output of `Sys.getenv()['PATH']`

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this issue when running an Rmarkdown `{Rcpp}` block on Windows 10. Rcpp had worked great in every other context.

1. Install Rtools40 (as @aromatic6tet) said, so that it appears in `C:\rtools40`
2. Restart machine
3. Open Rstudio
4. Type the following, note use of semicolon delimiter between path constant and use of double backslash.
   `Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin", sep = ";"))`

...and knitr now compiles Rcpp!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Florian Privé"
date: "12 septembre 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
Rcpp::cppFunction('
int fibonacci(const int x) {
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return(x);
    return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}') 
```

```{r}
fibonacci(10L)
```
# [1] 55
````

Comment: How exactly is that a workaround if, as we suspect, _he hasn't got a working Rcpp setup_ ?

Comment: I have a running Rcpp setup on my machine and was not able to run this example https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/029-engine-Rcpp.Rmd. So I presented the workaround above, because this works for me! Don´t no why, but that´s a fact. Perhaps the original poster has the same problems ...

Comment: Same error here.

Another info that may be useful: I use Rcpp for [this in-progress package](https://github.com/privefl/bigsnpr). The `Check` is "stopping" with an endless checking of examples. And `Build & Reload` is giving me an error. But if I use `Check`, stop it before the examples and then use `Build & Reload`, it works.. This package builds on Travis-CI and win-builder. I don't know if this issue is related, otherwise just forget it.

Comment: My error was similar to this. It was occuring because I had `cache = TRUE` in knittr options. Apparently Rccp functions don't play nice with cache. So to fix it I put `cache = FALSE` in the code block defining the Rcpp function.