# Rstudio can't find devtools

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I am trying to install R devtools, but RStudio can't find the library. I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885381/rtools-not-being-detected-by-r) and [this github discussion](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/101) which together might mean it is a Cygwin issue, but I have tried uninstalling git (and therefore my Cygwin copy) and reinstalling Rtools with no luck. Does anyone have ideas about other things to try?

My system:

Windows 10 with GIT bash installed (therefore Cygwin as well)

RStudio version 0.99.902

R version 3.3

```
> install.packages("devtools")
> library(devtools)
> find_rtools(T)
Error: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 127
```

My path (from within RStudio):

```
> Sys.getenv()['PATH']
PATH                                           C:\Program
                                               Files\R\R-3.3.0\bin\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
                                               Files\Git\cmd;C:\cygwin32;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program
                                               Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\king\Desktop\_REPOS\misc\stock_analysis\forex\oanda\ruby;C:\Users\king\.dnx\bin;C:\Program
                                               Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran in the same problems and the following [instructions](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/R/ICPSR/R-install-instructions.html) solved my problems. I am not sure any more, but I also think I had to set `.libPaths() = “C:/R/R-3.2.2/library”` (On windows)

Comment: In my case I just had to install RTools again, without modifying the `.libPaths()`