# Cannot install rtools

Tags: r, rtools

I need to install Rtools but I'm not having success.

When I run this it works

```
library(devtools)
find_rtools()
[1] TRUE
```

when I load the library, it also works fine. But when I run my code that needs rtools, I get:

```
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
```

and when I try to install rtools I get this:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)
```

**Solution**

Setting the path solved the problem. thank you @red_quark

[Rtools is not being detected from RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103203/rtools-is-not-being-detected-from-rstudio/44035904#44035904)

Comment: I think, these topics can help you. Check if you correctly installed path of Rtools. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103203/rtools-is-not-being-detected-from-rstudio/44035904#44035904, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619185/rcpp-cant-find-rtools-error-1-occurred-building-shared-library

Comment: Setting the paths solved the issue. thanks @red_quark!