# Which R version my PC currently Uses?

Tags: r, jri

Im currently using R through Java, and im not sure which version im using.

I've stetted in R studio my R version into version 2.15.3 which is what i need:
[image]

And so is my enviorment variable setting (R_home):

[image]

But typing in the command line : "R":

[image]

So which version in being used?

Comment: If you can run R code within your app, use R's `sessionInfo()`. To get just the version, check `sessionInfo()$R.version$version.string`.

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: My problem is that i don't know which R version is being used by Java

Comment: The Java output or the R output? the Problem is that the only way to view the R console output is that i need to use `sink()` , which means i need the R to work, right now im getting from Java the output `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51571/discussion-between-yehoshaphat-schellekens-and-tonytonov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you describe, you have the most updated version of R installed and RStudio is able to detect it. However the version of R that is currently in your OS environment variable (and hence used by Java) is not the most recent,

=> you need to update your PATH environment variable.
The procedure might be a bit different whether you are on Unix or Windows.

I am sure you'll find plenty of ressources on Internet to help you do that [How to update PATH variable permanently from cmd? Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358265/how-to-update-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd-windows)

Comment: I actually want the opposite, i want to downgrade the R version, that's why my R_home is set to 2.15.3, are you implying that by typing "R" in the command line, im getting the most recent R version and not the R version i specified on R_home manually?

Comment: Dude I'm sorry, your answer is a right answer, I guess I should have read it thorrowly before I wasted three houses until I found it myself