# Windows Cmd path, Sublime Path, System Variables

Tags: python, windows, path, cmd

I have python 3.4 installed on C:\Python34\ and I set the path via the GUI:

[image]

However Sublime and all the other programs still don't have the path set and wont run python:

[image]

Is there separate path variables in windows? why are these not the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, Had to modify the path this way

[How to update PATH variable permanently from cmd? Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358265/how-to-update-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd-windows?rq=1)

I am not sure what the difference is between a system path and user path, especially since the programs that needed the path were running on my account.