# Setting Python Path Permanently from cmd in windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, path, python-3.4

I have Python 3.4 installed on my C:\Python34 and I want to add this directory to my Path.

> **set path=%path%;C:\python34**

on command prompt (win7) does this but not permanently (only for that session).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a Python question, just a plain Windows question. Google for "windows modify path".

These steps are from [this page](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx):

1. From the desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
2. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab.
3. In the Advanced section, click the Environment Variables button.

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a special command for permanent setting, from cmd

Comment: That wasn't clear. In that case your question is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8358361/963195

Comment: @ketan: why from the command line?  There's no obvious reason why you would need to do it that way in the scenario you describe.

Comment: @ketan, or use the `reg` command. System environment variables get loaded by the session manager from the following registry key: `"HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"`.