# python 2.7 windows silent installer (.msi) - command-line option to set the path?

Tags: python, windows, installation, windows-installer

When installing python 2.7 on Windows using silent installer (.msi), is there a command-line option to add Python to path environment variable, like the GUI option?

Python 3.5 installer includes an option PrependPath=0 by default, but can Python 2.7 use it?

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Looks like this issue was discussed here, but no resolution for Python 2.7?

https://bugs.python.org/issue3561

EDIT

---

this batch command rocks!!!

setx \M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python\Python27;C:\Python\Python27\Scripts"

but setx will truncate the stored %PATH% string to 1024 bytes.

Comment: afaik you can set it through the registry .... if thats helpful ...

Comment: msi installer should add python to windows registry by default, but adding to path env. var. is different.

Comment: no i mean the PATH can be modified through the windows registry

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8358361/541038

Comment: @JoranBeasley add your answer, I'm going to accept it!

Answer (score 13):

The Python MSI installer can update the system path since 2.4. Just add **ADDLOCAL=ALL** to the command line. You'll have to restart your system before it propagates.

```
msiexec /i "python-2.7.11.amd64.msi" /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL
```

https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4/msi/

Comment: "You'll have to restart your system before it propagates." - this is not an option in my case.

Comment: Perhaps the author meant "restart prompt" instead of system. Running msiexec as above with ADDLOCAL=ALL successfully introduces python to PATH in your next cmd session.

Comment: Yes, Chris, I meant system restart. This option updates the registry but it does not force Windows Explorer/Shell to reload the new path value. There's a way to do that, but apparently the Python installer doesn't use it. So, if you launch a program from Explorer after running the installation, the new process inherits the old path, not the registry path. I haven't tested this in ~8 months. Maybe it's changed.

Comment: I just tested this on Windows XP (I know) and can confirm an entire restart was required after using `ADDLOCAL=ALL` with the Python 3.4 MSI installer.

Comment: Is restart needed also for 3.5.exe Installer? If i start Installer manually there is no need of restart. :/ I am dealing with this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310884/adding-into-path-var-while-silent-installation-of-python-possible-bug

Comment: I've been using this command line successfully for 2.7.14 and %PATH% updates seem to propagate 

msiexec /norestart /passive /log ".\python-2.7.14.amd64.log" /package ".\python-2.7.14.amd64.msi" ADDLOCAL=ALL

Answer (score 3):

I have observed that on Windows 7 (Professional) with python 2.7.14 x64, no restart is required for Python to be added to PATH.  Just start up a new command window after the install and python will be in the PATH.

You can determine whether or not a restart is required by the install by running the msi as follows:

```
start/wait "" msiexec /i "python-2.7.11.amd64.msi" /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL
if %errorlevel% == 3010 ( echo Success: reboot required ) else (if %errorlevel% == 0 ( echo Success ) else ( echo Installation failed with error code %errorlevel% ) )
```

That is, if `%errorlevel%` is 3010 (ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED), then a reboot will be required.  The use of `start/wait` causes cmd.exe to wait until the msiexec process finishes.  This allows the msiexec return status to be available to cmd.exe.

BTW You may wish to include the option `ALLUSERS=1` on the command line if you want the installation of Python to be available to all users on the system.