# Adding into Path var while silent installation of Python - possible bug?

Tags: python, windows, installation, windows-10, python-install

I need to passively install Python in my applications package installation so i use the following:

```
python-3.5.4-amd64.exe /passive PrependPath=1
```

according this: [3.1.4. Installing Without UI](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui) I use the PrependPath parameter which should add paths into Path in Windows environment variables.

But it seems not to work. The variables does not take any changes.

If i start installation manually and select or deselect checkbox with add into Paths then everything works.

Works same with clear installation also on modify current installation. Unfortunately i do not have other PC with Win 10 Pro to test it.

I have also tried it with Python 3.6.3 with same results.

**EDIT:**

Also tried with PowerShell `Start-Process python-3.5.4-amd64.exe -ArgumentList /passive , PretendPath=1` with same results.

Also tested on several PCs with Windows 10, same results, so the problem is not just on single PC

**EDIT:**
Of cource all attempts were run as administrator.

Comment: but it works for me ... on a windows 7 32bit box.

Comment: @georgexsh at Win 10 Pro not.

Comment: where is your codes ?

Comment: @IvanBarayev what code?

Comment: Still bugged Python 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, from my point of view it seems to be bug in Python Installer and I can not find any way how to make it works.

I have founds the following workaround:

Use py.exe which is wrapper for all version of Python on local machine located in C:\Windows so you can run it directly from CMD anywhere thanks to C:\Windows is standard content of Path variable.

```
py -3.5 -c "import sys; print(sys.executable[:-10])"
```

This gives me directory of python 3.5 installation.

And then i set it into Path manually by:

```
setx Path %UserProfile%";PythonLocFromPreviousCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

try powershell to do that

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow .\python.exe /passive
```

Comment: How can i add the PrependPath=1 argument? `Start-Process python-3.5.4-amd64.exe /passive` works but at `Start-Process python-3.5.4-amd64.exe /passive PrependPath=1` I have got the following error: `Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'PrependPath=1'.`

Comment: you can try `Start-Process -NoNewWindow .\python.exe -ArgumentList passive , PretendPath=1`

Comment: `.\python.exe -ArgumentList PrependPath=1` is what I was looking for. (Pre*p*endPath takes a p.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using an elevated command prompt (ie: run as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried to use the InstallAllUsers argument. By default it is set >to 0 so try to use it like this (which is the same example from [here][1]):
>
> python-3.6.0.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0
>   it migth make a difference to use the `/quiet` over `/passive`
>
> [1]: https://docs.python.org
>   /3.6/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui "the link you supplied"

To answer Erik Šťastný comment i believe that a good solution to your problem is to package python with your program to make sure that all the required libaries is preinstalled.

Comment: it seems there is no difference over /quiet or /passive. InstallAllUsers=1 options is really bad. Because if someone has already installed Python in user profile, then is whole installation aborted before reach end and nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the command line options for the python installer and noticed the same issue as you, and here's the solution I found:

1. Download the 64-bit installer from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
   (the link is titled "*Windows x86-**64** executable installer*")
2. Uninstall any current python installation.

   - You can use this command: `START python-3.8.3-amd64.exe /uninstall`
   - *(replace  python-3.8.3-amd64.exe  with the name of the file you downloaded).*
   - *(run cmd or your batch file as administrator, by right-clicking, then Run As Administrator).*
3. Install (as admin) python 64-bit for all users, **with the START command**:
   `START python-3.8.3-amd64.exe /passive PrependPath=1 Include_pip=1 InstallAllUsers=1`

   - *(replace  python-3.8.3-amd64.exe  with the name of the file you downloaded).*
   - *(run cmd or your batch file as administrator, by right-clicking, then Run As Administrator).*
   - *(More info on python installer command line options: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui).*
4. (Optional) Open a new cmd window to verify that python works from any location:

   - You can run this command:`python --version`
   - *(If you don't see output like "Python 3.8.3", then Python has not been added to your PATH).*
   - *(Note: That command didn't work until I opened a new command prompt window).*

For me, all of the details were important, so don't skip any.