# Command prompt does not recognize changes in PATH. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, path, pip

I am attempting to download modules in Python through pip. No matter how many times I edit the PATH to show the pip.exe, it shows the same error:
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have changed the PATH many different times and ways to make pip usable, but these changes go unnoticed by the command prompt terminal.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Is your `python` executable accessible from the command line? At least for me, `pip` is under `<python location>\Scripts`

Comment: if you change your PATH you have to reopen cmd.exe e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10411111/4711754

Comment: As you are speaking of `pip.exe`, I assume that you are using Windows. On Windows the recommended way is `py -m pip install ...`

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Show us the directory where `pip.exe` resides. Show us the original `PATH`, the way(s) you modify it and the resulting `PATH`.

Comment: As @phd noted you haven't given us enough information. You didn't even state the OS you're using or python version -- information that is almost always relevant to any question of this nature.

Comment: @KurtisRader `pip.exe` reveals the OS. :-)

Comment: @phd No, it doesn't. You're assuming MS Windows is the only OS to employ the .exe convention. Such assumptions are dangerous. And even if, as is likely, the O.P. is using windows knowing which version might be relevant. For example, are they doing this in a WSL session on Windows 10?

Comment: I am using Windows and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PyCharm? if yes change the environment to your desired directory and desired interpreter if you do have multiple interpreter available

Comment: If you're not using PyCharm. Try to add this to your Path <python location>;<python location>\Scripts. By doing this system can now locate the python.py inside the python location and the pip.py inside Scripts