# Tomcat: How do I set up a Java system property in Netbeans?

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables

How do I, from Netbeans, for use with Tomcat, set up an environment variable that I can read using `System.getProperty(...);`

> We have a source controlled project - and we're constantly making changes to confirurations that we "would" like to share (don't want to use svn:ignore). We're trying to set up one simple parameter, an environment variable to the config properties of our application. For example: mark.properties or john.properties. If the system can't find the environment variable, then it defaults to server.properties (for the live system).

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1. Go to the Tomcat Properties Platform Settings**

> In Netbeans, click the "Services" tag. Under "Servers", you'll see "Tomcat 7.0". Right click "Tomcat 7.0" and select "Properties". Then select the "Platform" tab.

**2. Under VM Options, add -Dvariable=value**

> Leave the D in place, and replace the variable with whatever variable name you'd like to set and value whatever value you'd like to set the variable to.

**3. Read out the property from your code.**

```
System.out.println("The value is " + System.getProperty("variable"));
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer is just in the NetBeans FAQ here:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSysPropsDuringRun

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.