# How to set Environment Variable in Netbeans?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, netbeans, maven-2

I am running maven based Spring project in netbeans .  I am using an environment variable in my project configurations file to Open specific file based on that variable value . I am able to set it In Eclipse but do not know how to set in Netbeans . Can any one help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a java environment variable in Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577249/how-do-i-set-up-a-java-environment-variable-in-netbeans)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577249/how-do-i-set-up-a-java-environment-variable-in-netbeans is not a duplicate because it's about system properties and not environment variables (the title said it the other way around, edit already suggested)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
System.getEnv("FOO") == "FOOVALUE"
```

netbeans 6.7+ -

Right click Project

- ->Properties
  ->Actions
  ->Run project
  ->Set Properties: Add

Env.FOO=FOOVALUE

Note: You can apply the same technique on other configurations and other actions like Debug project

Answer (score 3):

I could not find that Properties->Actions setting, using NetBeans 7.4.  I did not *explicitly* need an environment variable--just some value I could set outside my application. So, instead, I was able to make a change in the "project.properties" file under the nbproject folder of the main application.

Within project.properties is a "run.args.extra" setting.  Any command line argument you wish to pass along must have its 'name' preceded by '-J'.  Here is an example.

run.args.extra=-J-DFOO=FOOVALUE

Note that this is NOT an environment variable.  Rather, it is a System.getProperty("FOO") accessible value.  Of special note: this is also the place to change how much memory your applications allocate, using Xmx/Xms.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS:

In `$HOME/.bashrc` add alias:

`alias netbeans='/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ X.Y.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans &'`

In Terminal:

`> netbeans`

This will start IDE with user environment variables.

As result environment variables (such as `$PATH`) available inside NetBeans IDE and tools (such as Ruby debugger).