# DATABASE_URL not found even when it is set in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, nullpointerexception, environment-variables, database-connection

Hey guys I have a heroku web app with a PostgreSQL database. As you can see in the picture the `DATABASE_URL` is set:

[image: ev]

[image]

But for some reason when I try access the environment variable to connect to the database I get a `NullPointerException` because apparently the `DATABASE_URL` does not exist:

```
private static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {
  URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

  String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
  String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
  String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath();

  return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
}
```

[image: error]

What's going on here? How can I fix it?

Comment: What's the exact error and traceback? We need to know what, specifically, is generating the NPE.

Comment: Also, you've leaked a significant portion of your Postgres connection string (your entire username and a good chunk of your password). Before you do anything else, please [rotate your credentials](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-credentials). The ones in your screenshot are forever compromised.

Comment: @Chris this is just a test database I want use it for later purposes. The error occurs in the first line of code System.getenv cant find my database_url environment

Comment: Okay, now you've leaked two entire connection strings. Even if they're test databases, _please rotate their credentials **immediately**_.

Comment: Don't describe the error, _show it to us_. [`java.lang.System.getenv(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) should only throw `NullPointerException` if `name` is `null`. If the value isn't set this call should _return_ null. If that's what's happening, your error occurs when you call `.getUserInfo()` on it, or maybe when you instantiate a `URI` from it. But we shouldn't have to guess… please give us the exact error. See [ask].

Comment: @Chris yeah I changed the passwords of my databases. well yeah exactly. System.geenv(".."); returns a null value, because the url is not set. But how can it not be set when there is an environmental variable called "DATABASE_URL"

Comment: For the _last time, please **show us the exact error message**_. We're not going to take your word for what you think the problem is.

Comment: @Chris like the picture I edited?

Comment: That doesn't look like a regular Heroku build to me. What command are you running to generate that?

Comment: @Chris I am executing it via netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku config vars are [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). They're defined in and apply to a particular environment, in this case the environment in which an app runs on Heroku. They have no effect on other environments, for example ones on the machine sitting in front of you.

You can [configure NetBeans to use an environment variable for your project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8577249/354577) locally. The value of the `DATABASE_URL` here can be different from what it is on Heroku, just make sure to set it to a valid PostgreSQL URL value.

Comment: does that mean I can't access my database_url in the deployed heroku web app? because now I deployed my app on heroku and I used a test environmental variable to show it on the webpage but it does not show

Comment: @SavanLuffy, be careful with casing. Environment variables called `DATABASE_URL` and `database_url` are different. The variables you see via `heroku config` should be available in the apps you provide with the `-a` / `--app` option.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows

`write set DATABASE_URL=url address from Heroku`

For macOS

`export DATABASE_URL=url address from Heroku`

Make sure you have installed PostgreSQL first.