# how Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd ) runs an exe which requires outgoing proxy

Tags: java, linux, proxy, jvm, exe

I have Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd ) to run an exe file that downloads a content from another server.

but the program fails to connect to another server due to timeout.

seemingly the Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd ) does not use the proxy set in the JVM. It works when i set export https_proxy="host:port" manually on the server. Could you please suggest how to resolve it?

```
System.setProperty( "https.proxyHost", "host" )
System.setProperty( "https.proxyPort", "port" )
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "test.exe" ) >> fails to download a content from an external server
```

Comment: [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8607281/1059372)

Comment: `export https_proxy="host:port"` is basically the right answer, and your Java program should not be hard coding `System.setProperty( "https.proxyHost", "host" );`.  Proxy config should be the sysadmin's responsibility, and not the individual program's.

Comment: @Eugene how can sub process reuse the environment proxy configured in the main process?
`Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runtime.exec( "/bin/sh -c export https_proxy", new String[] { "https_proxy=host:port" } );
p.waitFor();

p = runtime.exec( "exe" ); << this is the new process and still not working
p.waitFor();`

otherwise another option is to run a sh file.

Comment: `/bin/sh -c export https_proxy` creates a new shell and alters that shell. It does not change the initiating process. Since the main process has not been altered, there is nothing to reuse in a sub process. And why don’t you just provide the `new String[] { "https_proxy=host:port" }` argument to the actual `exec` call? No-one suggested to make two `exec` calls.