# Where does Java's ProcessBuilder look to execute commands?

Tags: java, path, command, processbuilder

When I execute a command using `ProcessBuilder`, how does it know where to look for that command?  Using [this hack/trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java) I've modified my PATH variable (verified by inspecting `processBuilder.environment()`) to be bad (empty, working dir, etc) but ProcessBuilder can still execute sort, echo, bash, etc. just fine.  How is it doing this?!

Note: My particular development environment is OSX but this code will also run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says

> [...] a command, a list of strings which signifies the external program file to be invoked and its arguments, if any. Which string lists represent a valid operating system command is system-dependent. [...]

Which in essence mean that where it looks for programs to execute depends on the particular system and JVM you're running on.

I can't find a complete matrix of JVM / System behaviors, but supposedly it behaves similar to the popular shells of the system (`bash` for *nix and `cmd` for windows) i.e. it searches the directories in the `PATH` environment variable from left to right and executes the first executable file it finds.

Comment: I see you found my follow up question :-P  To clarify I am running on OSX and wondering if there is any way to modify where it looks.

Comment: Hmm.. beats me. Let's just wait and see if someone comes around and answers this. It seems like the `ProcessBuilder` must have some fallback mechanism which it checks in addition to the PATH variable.

Comment: 1.7.0_51 on OSX and I can't get it to look at PATH. Only full path in constructor works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take control of finding commands, then, well, take control of finding commands. Don't let `ProcessBuilder` search. Use your own code to find what you want to run, and then put an absolute pathname into the parameter to `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: I am trying to write a unit test for something that uses the ProcessBuilder to execute "sort", which wants ProcessBuilder to do the search.  I was just trying to simulate sort not being found.