# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() won't work in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse

I am running a python script located in my Eclipse project folder with the following Java code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python pythonscript.pyw");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

My console always reads null and my p.exitValue() is 2. However, typing the following in Windows command prompt works just fine and I get the correct output:

```
C:\users\user\workspace\project>python pythonscript.pyw
```

Does this have something to do with specifying my directory in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, most likely. Make sure `python` is found by `exec`. (Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368666/where-does-javas-processbuilder-look-to-execute-commands)

Comment: When happens if you run Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path"); ?

Comment: Your Java file and pythonscript.pyw file should be on the same directory for this to run..

Comment: if you can try this outside of eclipse ,you can check is it work .make sure .class file and .pyw lying inside same folder

Comment: @aioobe I put python in my PATH variable so I'm pretty sure `exec` can find it, especially if the command prompt works

Comment: @DarylYong can you manually run and check is it work.create  .java class inside a folder and put .pyw inside it .compile and run using cmd .

Comment: @4k3R I put the .pyw file together with the .java files in workspace\project\src\package and it doesn't work

Comment: @FastSnail I also tried putting the .pyw file together with the .class files in workspace\project\bin\package and it doesn't work

Comment: @DarylYong well plz add this code to your main method 
`System.out.println("Working Directory = "
                + System.getProperty("user.dir"));` and check is it same as where you put your python file.

this will show you where you should  put your python file

Comment: You can't put "pythonscript.pyw" inside your project src/class context, Python won't be able to find it, it must reside within a relative location to the execution context of your program. Try using ProcessBuilder instead, as it allows you to control the execution context of the process, amongst other things. A exit code of 2 yip ally means that the executable can't be found

Comment: You shuld put your pyw script to working directory of running java application.

Answer (score 0):

You can run such command:

```
String scriptDir = "./some dir";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"cd " + scriptDir + " && python pythonscript.pyw\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aioobe for the link! After checking ProcessBuilder.environment() I realized that Python wasn't in there (even though it's in my PATH system environment variable, weird huh?)
So I included the absolute path to my pythonw.exe and it worked just fine :) This is my edited code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/python34/pythonw.exe pythonscript.pyw");
```