# How to set environmental variables in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables

How (where?) can I set Environment Variables using IntelliJ idea?

For instance, I am looking forward to set the `$APP_HOME` (my tests rely on).

Where can this be done please?

Comment: I know it is old question, but if there are other like me who arrived here because my env variables were secrets comming initially from a Hashicorp Vault, Instead of duplicating them in my intellij run configs, I use a maven plugin to inject my env variables into my run/debug execution.
https://homeofthewizard.github.io/vault-maven-plugin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most run configurations have an option to set environment variables:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The build settings window has a configuration tab with an option to change the environment variables.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-application.html

Otherwise you can use system system calls or the java language itself to change them during runtime.

[How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)