# How to add an environment variable in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

I'm working on Java. I have to add an environment variable in java code programmatic such that it will be available when i get list using process builder as follows:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class helloworld  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("export MY_ENV_VAR=1");

        Map<String, String> envMap = pb.environment();

        Set<String> keys = envMap.keySet();
        for(String key:keys){
            System.out.println(key+" ==> "+envMap.get(key));
        }

    }
}
```

But with above trial i cant get environment variable properly.
so How to set the environment variable ?

Comment: Have you tried `pb.environment().put("key", "value");` ?

Comment: @berry120 ya its kide of, but i did not get exact answer.

Comment: ```java
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1457)
 at br.com.stilingue.services.remove_occupation.RemoveOccupationTest.setUpTestEnv(RemoveOccupationTest.java:29)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("MV_ENV_VAR", "1");
```

would set MY_ENV_VAR=1. Before you invoke  the Process by

```
Process p = pb.start();
```

`export` would only be interpreted by a shell.

See also [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

A full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("CMD", "/C", "SET");
    Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
    env.put("MYVAR", "myValue");
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    while (!isr.ready()) {
        ;
    }
    while (isr.read(buf) != -1) {
        System.out.println(buf);
    }
}
```

prints among other environment values:

```
MYVAR=myValue
```

This should prove that the created process uses the manipulated environment.

Comment: thanks, but env.put("MV_ENV_VAR", "1"); will set the env variable only in local variable, but if u again take processbuilder instance and get the content of map, it will not show the variable that we have set as mentioned by you.

Comment: @BSalunke updated my answer and added an example.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the desired variables directly into `ProcessBuilder.environment()` map.
The code below should work:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class helloworld  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh"); // or any other program you want to run

    Map<String, String> envMap = pb.environment();

    envMap.put("MY_ENV_VAR", "1");
    Set<String> keys = envMap.keySet();
    for(String key:keys){
        System.out.println(key+" ==> "+envMap.get(key));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @masksim_khokhlov what if we again took the processBuilder instance and get the contained of map? it will not contain our variable

Comment: @BSalunke Why it won't? It will! ProcessBuilder.environment() will always return the same `Map` instance. Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can get the environment variable with the process Builder object :

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
    Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
    env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
    env.remove("OTHERVAR");
    env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
```

Comment: It looks like `pb.start()` is missing.