# Update PATH Environment variable independant of OS using JAVA

Tags: java, windows, unix, environment-variables

How can I update the environment variable PATH using java. With the same code I should be able to update the PATH variable in Windows and Unix when I run the code in respective OS.

Thanks in advance.

regards,
San

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Answer (score 0):

In Unix  (c language) you can change the PATH by using the different forms of "exec" command, but it can only be used to pass additional/updated variables to whatever will be executed by the current program.

One of the principles of Unix is that the environment is unchanged from what it was when you started to execute your code. So, even if your code (java) is executed thru a JVM, it will still have to comply to this rule. Once the JVM exits, all updates to PATH are lost.

This is not the case in Windows. A program can change the current environment, which is why you often find yourself in a different directory after you executed some code on a windows platform.

Unfortunately, because of this, you will not have a means of doing that in both Windows and Unix. The best you can hope for in Unix is to have something like this:

myScript.sh:

```
# This is a script that executes the program and then 'includes' a script
/path/to/my/program  # which writes the following file containing environment changes
. /this/file/created/by/above
```

in 'shell' interpreter (command prompt if you prefer):

```
# Execute my program using myScript.sh
. ./myScript.sh
```

This should preserve your path change but you can never call 'myScript.sh' without the leading dot. If you forgot it, you could do an include of the "/this/file/created/by/above" after the execution.

Of course when you use this you need to handle possible simultaneous execution by multiple users. So the file "/this/file/created/by/above" should be distinct for each execution. Investigate the possible use of "$$" parameter.

Ps. "/path/to/my/program" can be a JVM that will execute your java code.

Security: If I was a "root" user I would definitively not want to execute your code. Your program could put anything in that file "/this/file/created/by/above" and it would get executed by root.