# Change content of batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, process, runtime.exec

How to change content of batch file using Java code?

I worked with parsing XML using Java program. It worked fine. But can I do same for the batch file using Java?

I am able to run batch file using below code.

```
String command = "cmd /c start " + batFile;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(command);
```

The content of my batch file is:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceMonitor
start SourceMonitor.exe /C "C:\shravani-workspace\appanalytix\src\main\resources\appanalysis.xml"
exit
```

But before doing this I want to change location

```
C:\shravani-workspace\appanalytix\src\main\resources\appanalysis.xml
```

..to user given XML location. How can I achieve this in my Java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about passing command line args to the bat file like so:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SourceMonitor
start SourceMonitor.exe /C %1
exit
```

Then modify your java code to pass in the XML file name after the bat file name

Comment: U mean me to excecute somting like with following code? String command = "cmd /c start " + batFile +" C:\shravani-workspace\appanalytix\src\main\resources\appanalysis.xml";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(command);

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not posting the java code. I was answering this from my phone =)

Comment: sorry sorry it worked for me thank you for your example answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use an environment variable instead. This way you don't need to edit the batch file, just set the variable before running it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java) or [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/584969/java/java/set-environment-variable) see how to set an environment variable from java and [here's](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121170) how to use them in a batch file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you - I'm really proud of it ;)