# Java program setting an environment variable

Tags: java, environment

Is there a way to have a Java program set an environment variable in Windows and/or Linux system?

I'm creating a Java application for a desktop system, which I hope will be used in Windows, Linux and Mac. But I'm unsure if I can make the installer set an environment variable for the application.

Comment: you want that variable read by non jvm process?

Comment: Here's how:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Comment: I was thinking of setting an [name]_home for the application i.e. so that other apps of the suite could always point to the right SQLite db.

Answer (score 3):

The environment is only ever passed *into* a child process, never *out of* a child process. So if what you want is to be able to write something like this:

```
java ProgramThatSetsAnEnvironmentVariable
java ProgramThatUsesTheEnvironmentVariable
```

then no, that's not possible.

But if what you want is to for a Java program to run a program, and you want it to pass in additional environment variables, then yes, that's possible, by using [`java.lang.ProcessBuilder`'s `environment()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via reflection.

Use the following code:

```
public static void setEnv(String key, String value) {
    try {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        Class<?> cl = env.getClass();
        Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, String> writableEnv = (Map<String, String>) field.get(env);
        writableEnv.put(key, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to set environment variable", e);
    }
}
```