# Delete 'CATALINA_HOME' user variable or update the 'CATALINA_HOME' name to 'CATALINA_HOME_1' using java code

Tags: java, tomcat7

I would like to delete the 'CATALINA_HOME' using java code. Please let me know if someone know this type of problem.

Suppose already set 'CATALINA_HOME' = C:\Program Files\Apache

While installing the software, my software should use the my customize tomcat7
and that store in different location.

'CATALINA_HOME' = D:\Installer\Apache

while running the software it find the tomcat this location 'CATALINA_HOME' = C:\Program Files\Apache but my location is 
'CATALINA_HOME' = D:\Installer\Apache

Comment: Why you need to do so?

Comment: Delete the entry in file in which you want to modify.

Comment: CATALINA_HOME is defined in a file, generally on catalina.sh. You can modify it as any other regular file if you have access to it.

Comment: What _is_ the question exactly?

Comment: look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to delete the 'CATALINA_HOME' using java code.

Sorry, but you can't.  A program (at least on Linux / Unix / Solaris) cannot modify the environment of its parent shell.  At most, a program only sees a *snapshot* of its parent's environment variables ... as they were when the parent `fork`s the child process.

(Windows variables work a bit differently, but I think the same restriction applies ...)

The only thing that a Java can do (reliably / portably) is to change the environment variables that a child process of your Java process will inherit.  You can do that using `ProcessBuilder`.

---

Now in theory, a program *could* attempt to modify the source of the variables' values:

- On a Unix like system, they *often* come from one of the shell's RC files; e.g. `$HOME/.profile`, `$HOME/.bashrc` and so on ... depending on the shell.  Or the variable may have been set in the "init" script that launches Tomcat.
- On a Windows system, the *may* have come from the registry, or a BAT file or ...

The problem is two-fold:

- It is impossible to be entirely sure where the value really comes from.
- Even if you can be sure, changing the source of the value won't affect the respective shell's *current* value for the variable.

---

Note: this is not a shortcoming of Java.  You would have the same problem when coding in C, C++, Python ...