# Setting environment variable in Java 8

Tags: java, testing, reflection, junit, environment-variables

I have similar code to this one ([update environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7201825/1679995)):

```
private static void setEnv(Map<String, String> envs) {
    try {
        Class<?> pec = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment");
        Field tef = pec.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment");
        tef.setAccessible(true);

        Map<String, String> env = (Map<String, String>) tef.get(null);
        env.clear();
        env.putAll(envs);

        Field tcief = pec.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment");
        tcief.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, String> cienv = (Map<String, String>) tcief.get(null);
        cienv.clear();
        cienv.putAll(envs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.printStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

I've written some unit tests for this code and now I'm testing on Java 8 (1.8.0). This code doesn't work for `Run` in JUnit, but works when is running as `Debug` (with and without breakpoints).
Doesn't work means I get my environment variable (PATH) like this

```
String path = System.getenv("PATH");
```

and I see there is no my path (`c:\\temp`). Testing on Java 7 (1.7.0_51) works fine, all Javas are 32-bit, I'm using no additional threads. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the case sensitivity keys. Parameter `envs` was created as

```
Map<String, String> envs = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

but creating it as

```
Map<String, String> envs = new TreeMap<String, String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

solved the problem. I got different results for `env["Path"]`, `env["PATH"]` and so on.

Comment: Give yourself credit by accepting your own question.

Comment: I couldn't do it in 24 hours after posting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using System Stubs - https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs

```java
Map<String, String> someMap = ...; // work out the env variables
EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables(someMap);
```

The environment variables are applied to the environment while the object is active. This is achieved either through its JUnit 4 or 5 plugins, or via using the `execute` method on the object to wrap around the executable code.