# Unable to start hive server in java program

Tags: java, hive

I am trying to start a Hive server using Java program.

This is my Java code.

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/bigdata/hive/bin/hive --service hiveserver");
p.waitFor();
```

Error:

`Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path`

I started my hdfs. But also i am getting this error

Comment: maybe you wanna read this article: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/
at this section : `Update $HOME/.bashrc`

Comment: Have you configured `HADOOP_HOME` to the hadoop folder?

Comment: I am configured in .bashrc

Comment: All six nodes running in hadoop. Hadoop single node installed perfectly and configured in .bashrc, But also While running this code i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.exec() is not going to run your .bashr, see [Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files). Your exec() call process should inherit your caller environemnt, but apparently the caller is missing the HADOOP_HOME. I can't guess why is that, probably something related to how/when is your own Java program invoked. One way to fix it is to run `bash -l -c hive --service ...` if you want bash to run the startup files and then run your command. But probably a better approach is to explicitly set the environment you want to pass down to your process. See [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

Ultimately, why? Usually all hive services should be started from init.d