# Editing Windows Environment Variables Not Working

Tags: java, environment-variables, windows-8.1

How to edit system or user variables on Windows using Java code and [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)? I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java) question but it doesn't seem to help. Why don't the following two code snippets work?

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class Environment
{
    public interface WinLibC extends Library
    {
        WinLibC INSTANCE = (WinLibC) Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt",
                WinLibC.class);

        public int _putenv(String name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WinLibC.INSTANCE._putenv("MYVARIABLE=MYVALUE");
    }
}
```

and

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class Environment
{
    WinLibC clib = (WinLibC) Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt", WinLibC.class);

    public Environment()
    {
        setenv("myVariable", "myValue");
    }

    public interface WinLibC extends Library
    {
        public int _putenv(String name);
    }

    public void setenv(String variable, String value)
    {
        clib._putenv(variable + "=" + value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Environment();
    }
}
```

Instead of writing the environment variable, nothing happens.

Comment: Why are you showing us JNA `printf` code in a question about manipulating environment variables?

Comment: @Andrew Medico: As an example for mapping native functions.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the people who can answer this don't need an example of calling a totally unrelated function.

Comment: @Andrew Medico: It's useful for people to provide an example code when they don't program Java but C or whatever and know the libraries

Comment: Thanks, the code you sent was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need JNA to get environment variables.
`System.getenv()` does exactly that.

On the other hand, it's generally a bad idea to *set* persistent environment variables in Java. It makes your program less portable (different systems have different notions of environment variable visibility/persistence), and it muddies the distinction between the JVM and the actual system's environment.

Of course, if you absolutely *have* to, you need to use [setenv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html) on Linux/Unix and [_putenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83zh4e6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on Windows.

Comment: It's not a bad idea when I want to make a Java program to do persistent environment variable changes and just that. I'll see if I can get it to work using your tips :)