# Appending environmental varibles programmatically to current process

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Main intention is to set the environment variables through java code.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("export MY_ENV=123");
```

Always returns a new process. But I want it to be executed for the current process .. Is there a way to append output to the current process?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: This has been answered [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java). It's not a good idea to change the whole question like that. I suggest you revert your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

- `inheritIO` lets you hook up the streams of the started process with the current process
- `waitFor` allows you to wait for the external process to finish

Example:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/ls").inheritIO()
                             .start()
                             .waitFor();
```

Comment: inheritIo() method worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 0):

The `Process` returned from the `exec` call contains three streams:

1. `process.getOutputStream()` which, if you write to, will be 'piped' in to the running process
2. `process.getInputStream()` which, if read from, will contain the standard output (the `ls` output)
3. `process.getErrorStream()` whihc, if read from, will contain the standard error output (error messages from running `ls`, if any).

It is your responsibility as the programmer, to read from these streams, and to output them to your program's output, if that's what you want.

Also, you should check the `process.exitValue()` if you want to get that too.

it is somewhat common to set up separate threads to monitor the Stdout and Stderr streams