# Can JAVA change environment variables?

Tags: java, windows-7

I can get environment variable like this

```
final String value = System.getenv("PE_CONF_PWD");
```

But how can I change environment variables ??

Comment: which platform are you using?

Comment: Change them for your process (don't make `value` final)? Or launch a new process with a modified environment?

Comment: I want to overwrite / write the actual env vars of my windows.

Comment: [How do I set environment variables from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java). Are you looking for this?

Comment: You can only set them in the processes your code called, not the one which called your code.

Answer (score 2):

The Java System class doesn't let you set environment variables for you Operating system directly. You can retrieve them using getenv() but there is no equivalent setenv() method.
When you start up the JVM, it copies your os's environment into its own Map of Strings. The actual container it uses is an unmodifiable map, probably to be extra safe.
So in a running Java application you have 2 environments: the JVM copy that you can read via System.getenv() and the underlying environment that lives in the C library.
You should be able to change the JVM's copy using [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html#package_description).