# Can I set an Environment Variable for Java Native Interface (JNI) libraries?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, environment-variables, native

I have a cross-platform Java application that relies on some native (C++) libraries for calling functions that perform complex scientific calculations. The native libraries are accessed using JNI (with SWIG-generated glue code). The libraries access several environment variables for configuration and location of various data tables, etc.
I would like my Java application to be able to set these environment variables, at least in the context of the JNI libraries. This would be easy if Java provided a way to set environtment variables in it's own shell/context, but it doesn't.

I've seen answers to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java) that require changing variables for Java itself or for child processes. This question is different because it relates specifically to JNI-called code. My guess is that the situation is identical because the JNI code presumably runs in the same environment as the Java application itself. 
However, I thought I'd ask just in case there is some JNI setting or method that could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. Environment variables are tied to the process. No difference between JNI and not-JNI.

You should be able to use another JNI library to set the environment for the other library running in the same process to pick up.

Comment: What 'other' JNI library would do such a feature?

Comment: @Holger One that you write and have under your control.

Comment: Oh that one. Thanks. :-)