# What is the earliest way to call a Java/Scala method?

Tags: java, scala, environment-variables

I use some dirty code to set environment variable in Scala from [second answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)

I test this in IDE(IDEA Intellij) and set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` at the beginning of my class.

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
class MyTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  val m = Map("OMP_NUM_THREADS" -> "1")
  EnvHacker.setEnv(m)
```

After set, I could read from `System.env`, it works. But when my program runs, it does not use this. I tried set it in static block, but still not work.

But if I set it in IDE run configuration(before JVM run), it works and runs as I expect. So seems it is read before I modify the variable.

Or in other word, I have a piece of code, what is the **earliest** way to call it in Java/Scala. e.g. static block is called before the first line of main method.

##### Some details updated:

I am using tensorflow-mkl Java API, it would read System environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` at some time, according to my test result, this operation is before the system static block. However, I want to control in code because I do not know the configuration expected without code logic.

Comment: How does your program retrieves this environment variable? Could it be that it retrieves it before you run your `EnvHacker.setEnv`?

Comment: @GaëlJ I think so, so is there any condition that it retrieves before the first line of running code?

Comment: It all depends on where/when your program retrieves this environment variable. If this is part of a framework/library you use, either they provided some kind of "hooks" which you can call before their code run, or it's probably a dead end.

Comment: To clarify, do you need this environment variable only in some tests or at runtime of the app?

Comment: at run time, I want to do some more control of process, but do not want to create other process at this time. If no way, maybe I would create another using ProcessBuilder

Comment: @GaëlJG I tested to set the environment variable at static block(before code execution), but still does not work.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks for your answer, I have simplified the question according to your help.

Comment: You sample code is specific to test case with scalatest. Do you want a solution which works with scalatest ? Solution to this problem is highly dependent on how you are "running" your code. Scalatest provides with [beforeAndAfter](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#beforeAndAfter) hook for such purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you want to control OpenMP via "OMP_NUM_THREADS" env but you can't or don't want to set the actual environment variables on your process for some reason? Is that right?

How are you invoking OpenMP? OpenMP is a C lib https://www.openmp.org/ , so it won't notice any changes you make to the `java.lang.ProcessEnvironment#theEnvironment` field, no matter how early you set it.

If you are invoking OpenMP via an `exec` call, then you should be able to pass a new environment to it.

If you are invoking OpenMP via JNI, then you won't be able to change your environment variables from Java, you will need to actually set the env when you start the process. See [Can I set an Environment Variable for Java Native Interface (JNI) libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816301/can-i-set-an-environment-variable-for-java-native-interface-jni-libraries)

Could you instead use `omp_set_num_threads()` rather than `OMP_NUM_THREADS` env?

Comment: Exactly! This is an XY problem. I add some details of the question. You said "you won't be able to change your environment variables from Java", but the hacking code seems to work. So that is turns out tensorflow-mkl java api does not invoke OpenMP from JNI? Am I getting it right?

Comment: I don't know how tensorflow-mkl java invokes OpenMP and I can't figure it out from 5 mins of googling. I think your real question is more like "how do I control the number of threads used by OpenMP inside tensorflow-mkl java", but I'm not very familiar with that toolchain. I think in an ideal world you would close this question and open a new question with that title and with some details of your setup, but if you have a solution that works for you then maybe that is not needed. This question won't be useful to any other Java devs as it has a misleading title IMO. GL!

Answer (score -1):

I *think* this might do what you want, I borrowed the env hacker (very nasty hack!) from the other question, my understanding is you want to set some environment variables and have them available in the main method (essentially as early as possible).

```scala
import java.util.{Collections, Map => JavaMap}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object EnvHacker {
    /**
     * Portable method for setting env vars on both *nix and Windows.
     * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7201825/293064
     */
    def setEnv(newEnv: Map[String, String]): Unit = {
        try {
            val processEnvironmentClass = Class.forName("java.lang.ProcessEnvironment")
            val theEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theEnvironment")
            theEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true)
            val env = theEnvironmentField.get(null).asInstanceOf[JavaMap[String, String]]
            env.putAll(newEnv.asJava)
            val theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField = processEnvironmentClass.getDeclaredField("theCaseInsensitiveEnvironment")
            theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.setAccessible(true)
            val cienv = theCaseInsensitiveEnvironmentField.get(null).asInstanceOf[JavaMap[String, String]]
            cienv.putAll(newEnv.asJava)
        } catch {
            case e: NoSuchFieldException =>
                try {
                    val classes = classOf[Collections].getDeclaredClasses
                    val env = System.getenv()
                    for {cl <- classes} {
                        if (cl.getName == "java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap") {
                            val field = cl.getDeclaredField("m")
                            field.setAccessible(true)
                            val obj = field.get(env)
                            val map = obj.asInstanceOf[JavaMap[String, String]]
                            map.clear()
                            map.putAll(newEnv.asJava)
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    case e2: Exception => e2.printStackTrace()
                }

            case e1: Exception => e1.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}


class Main extends {
  val NumThreads = "OP_NUM_THREADS"
  EnvHacker.setEnv(Map(NumThreads -> "100"))
}

object Main extends Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(System.getenv(NumThreads)) // prints 100
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this comment is not very related to the question