# Is it possible to "fool" java that an environment variable is set from the command line

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, jvm-languages

I'm running in an environment where I can pass parameters but not set environment variables using a normal commandline.

I would like to set environment variables nevertheless. Is there an alternative way to "fool" java that an environment variable is set, e.g. using -D parameters?

(I'm running spark in oozie through hue; all in the Cloudera stack).

Comment: Does this environment allow you to provide and run JARs of your choice?

Comment: When you say, "set environment variables using a normal command line," do you just mean running commands to set them in the current process? Or do you just mean you can't set them globally? Or what? Environment variables are orthogonal to command lines, so I can't really make sense of what your restrictions are.

Comment: If you can control the command line, you can set environment variable like this: `FOO=bar java ....`

Comment: @Buddy I can't. That is the whole basis of this question.

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't have a commandline. I don't have the ability to specify environment variables with the granularity I need at some higher level of process. What I have is oozie, a workflow manager.

Comment: @das-g Yes, it does.

Comment: Not sure this is what you're using, but maybe this will help: https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/Control-Scripts. It shows a way to tell the system environment variables to set. Is that the Cloudera stack you're using?

Comment: seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz How do you figure?

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks, I am using Cloudera stack. However, that is a different part of the stack. I am specifically asking about launching jobs through oozie, a workflow manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `java` command itself doesn't seem to allow that. It has a `-D` parameter, but that sets [Java 'system properties'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
$ java -help 2>&1 | grep -A1 '\-D' 
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
```

Java system properties are a sort of Java properties. Like environment variables, [java properties are key-value pairs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html), but aren't the same thing as environment variables: If your Java application reacts to a specific environment variable, setting a system property of the same name won't have any effect unless the application explicitly reacts to that property, too.

If your environment allows you to run arbitrary Java applications and if it allows your Java applications to execute other processes, you can write a little wrapper that sets the environment variables on a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (see the question Arnon linked in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304532/is-it-possible-to-fool-java-that-an-environment-variable-is-set-from-the-comma/31312993#comment50605268_31304532): [How do I set environment variables from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318239/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-from-java)) to then invoke `java` with your actual JAR from it. You could either hard-code the environment variables to set, or set them according to system properties the wrapper receives. (Or you could even implement your own shell in Java and pass a script to it.)

Though, if you can modify the source of that actual JAR, a much **more idiomatic solution** would be to make it itself react to properties instead of (or additionally to) environment variables. (Unless you have to control environment variables that the java command / the JVM reacts to rather than the JAR you'd like to run. Then this approach would not be applicable, of course.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run arbitrary Java code, you can create and run a Process using ProcessBuilder, including an environment of your choice.

Hence, write a java program that parses a command-line like

```
java -cp .... your.Prog FOO=BAR BAZ=BOOM command arguments ...
```

and starts `command` with the environment extended by `FOO` and `BAZ`
(Note that `command` could be `java` ...)